# Getting xpath indices to count forward to preserve table structure

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Scraping tables from the web get complicated when there are 2 or more values in a cell. In order to preserve the table structure, I have devised a way to count the row-number index of its xpath, implementing a nested list when the row number stays the same.

```py
    def get_structured_elements(name):
        """For target data that is nested and structured,
        such as a table with multiple values in a single cell."""
        driver = self.driver
    
        i = 2 # keep track of 'i' to retain the document structure.
        number_of_items ＝ number_of_items_found()
        elements = [None] * number_of_items # len(elements) will exceed number_of_items.

        target_data = driver.find_elements("//table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]/a")
    
        while i - 2 < number_of_items:
            for item in target_data:
                # print(item.text, i-1)
                if elements[i - 2] == None:
                    elements[i - 2] = item.text # set to item.text value if position is empty. 
                else:
                    elements[i - 2] = [elements[i - 2]] 
                    elements[i - 2].append(item.text) # make nested list and append new value if position is occupied.
            i += 1
    
        return elements
```

This simple logic was working fine, until I sought to manage all locator variables in one place to make the code more reusable: How do I store this expression `"//table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]/a"` in a list or dictionary so that it still works when plugged in?

The solution (i.e. hack) I came up with is a function that takes in the front and back half of the iterating xpath as arguments, returning `front_half + str(i) + back_half` if `i` is part of the parent (iterator) function's local variable.

```py
def split_xpath_at_i(front_half, back_half):
    """Splits xpath string at its counter index. 
    The 'else' part is to aviod errors 
    when this function is called outside an indexed environment. """
    
    if 'i' in locals():
        string = front_half + str(i) + back_half
    else:
        string = front_half+"SPLIT_i"+back_half

    return string

xpath = [split_xpath_at_i("//table/tbody/tr[","]/td[2]/a"), 
         "//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]"
        ]

def xpath_index_iterator():
    for i in range(10):
        print(split_xpath_at_i("//table/tbody/tr[","]/td[2]/a"))


xpath_index_iterator()

# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[SPLIT_i]/td[2]/a
```

Problem is, `split_xpath_at_i` is blind to variables in its immediate environment. What I eventually came up with is to make use of the iterator function's *attribute* to define the counter `i` so that the variable can be made available to `split_xpath_at_i` like so:

```py
def split_xpath_at_i(front_half, back_half):
    """Splits xpath string at its counter index. 
    The 'else' part is to aviod errors 
    when this function is called outside an indexed environment. """
    try:
        i = xpath_index_iterator.i
    except:
        pass
    
    if 'i' in locals():
        string = front_half + str(i) + back_half
    else:
        string = front_half+"SPLIT_i"+back_half

    return string

xpath = [split_xpath_at_i("//table/tbody/tr[","]/td[2]/a"), 
         "//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]"
        ]
    
def xpath_index_iterator():
    xpath_index_iterator.i = 0
    lst = []
    for xpath_index_iterator.i in range(10):
        print(split_xpath_at_i("//table/tbody/tr[","]/td[2]/a"))

xpath_index_iterator()

# //table/tbody/tr[0]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/a
# //table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a
```

The problem gets more complicated when I try to invoke `split_xpath_at_i` via a locator list:

```py
def split_xpath_at_i(front_half, back_half):
    """Splits xpath string at its counter index. 
    The 'else' part is to aviod errors 
    when this function is called outside an indexed environment. """
    try:
        i = xpath_index_iterator.i
    except:
        pass
    
    if 'i' in locals():
        string = front_half + str(i) + back_half
    else:
        string = front_half+"SPLIT_i"+back_half

    return string

xpath = [split_xpath_at_i("//table/tbody/tr[","]/td[2]/a"), 
         "//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a[1]"
        ]
    
def xpath_index_iterator():
    xpath_index_iterator.i = 0
    lst = []
    for xpath_index_iterator.i in range(10):
#         print(split_xpath_at_i("//table/tbody/tr[","]/td[2]/a"))
        lst.append(xpath[0])
    return lst

xpath_index_iterator()

# ['//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a',
#  '//table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/a']
```

What would a professional approach to this problem look like?

---

## The Entire Code:

The code below was modified from the [Selenium manual](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html).

I've asked a related question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67866614/6210219) that concerns the general approach to Page Objects design.

### test.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from query import Input
import page

cnki = Input()
driver = cnki.webpage('http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/')

current_page = page.MainPage(driver)
current_page.submit_search('禮學')
current_page.switch_to_frame()
result = page.SearchResults(driver)

structured = result.get_structured_elements('titles') # I couldn't get this to work.
simple = result.simple_get_structured_elements() # but this works fine.
```

### query.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver

class Input:
    """This class provides a wrapper around actual working code."""
    
    # CONSTANTS
    
    URL = None
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome
    
    def webpage(self, url):
        driver = self.driver()
        driver.get(url)
        
        return driver
```

### page.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from element import BasePageElement
from locators import InputLocators, OutputLocators
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement):
    """This class gets the search text from the specified locator"""

    #The locator for search box where search string is entered
    locator = None


class BasePage:
    """Base class to initialize the base page that will be called from all
    pages"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

class MainPage(BasePage):
    """Home page action methods come here. I.e. Python.org"""

    search_keyword = SearchTextElement()
    
    def submit_search(self, keyword):
        """Submits keyword and triggers the search"""
        SearchTextElement.locator = InputLocators.SEARCH_FIELD
        self.search_keyword = keyword

    def select_dropdown_item(self, item):
        driver = self.driver
        by, val = InputLocators.SEARCH_ATTR
        driver.find_element(by, val + "/option[text()='" + item + "']").click()

    def click_search_button(self):
        driver = self.driver
        element = driver.find_element(*InputLocators.SEARCH_BUTTON)
        element.click()
        
    def switch_to_frame(self):
        """Use this function to get access to hidden elements. """
        driver = self.driver
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        driver.switch_to.frame('iframeResult')

    # Maximize the number of items on display in the search results.
    def max_content(self):
        driver = self.driver
        max_content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#id_grid_display_num > a:nth-child(3)')
        max_content.click()
    
    
    def stop_loading_page_when_element_is_present(self, locator):
        driver = self.driver
        
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
    
        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        driver.execute_script("window.stop();")


    def next_page(self):
        driver = self.driver

        self.stop_loading_page_when_element_is_present(InputLocators.NEXT_PAGE)
        driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    
        try:
            driver.find_element(*InputLocators.NEXT_PAGE).click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")
        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("Last page reached")
        
        
  
        
class SearchResults(BasePage):
    """Search results page action methods come here"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        i = None # get_structured_element counter
        
    def wait_for_page_to_load(self):
        driver = self.driver
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(*InputLocators.MAIN_BODY))
    
    def get_single_element(self, name):
        """Returns a single value as target data."""
        driver = self.driver
        target_data = driver.find_element(*OutputLocators.CNKI[str(name.upper())])
        # SearchTextElement.locator = OutputLocators.CNKI[str(name.upper())]
        # target_data = SearchTextElement()
        return target_data
    
    def number_of_items_found(self):
        """Return the number of items found on a single page."""
        driver = self.driver
        target_data = driver.find_elements(*OutputLocators.CNKI['INDEX'])
        
        return len(target_data)
    
    def get_elements(self, name):
        """Returns simple list of values in specific data field in a table."""
        driver = self.driver
        target_data = driver.find_elements(*OutputLocators.CNKI[str(name.upper())])
        
        elements = []
        for item in target_data:
            elements.append(item.text)
        
        return elements


    def get_structured_elements(self, name):
        """For target data that is nested and structured,
        such as a table with multiple values in a single cell."""
        driver = self.driver

        i = 2 # keep track of 'i' to retain the document structure.
        number_of_items = self.number_of_items_found()
        elements = [None] * number_of_items

        while i - 2 < number_of_items:
            
            target_data = driver.find_elements(*OutputLocators.CNKI[str(name.upper())])

            for item in target_data:
                print(item.text, i - 1)
                if elements[i - 2] == None:
                    elements[i - 2] = item.text
                elif isinstance(elements[i - 2], list):
                    elements[i - 2].append(item.text)
                else:
                    elements[i - 2] = [elements[i - 2]]
                    elements[i - 2].append(item.text)
            i += 1
    
        return elements
    
    def simple_get_structured_elements(self):
        """Simple structured elements code with fixed xpath."""
        driver = self.driver

        i = 2 # keep track of 'i' to retain the document structure.
        number_of_items = self.number_of_items_found()
        elements = [None] * number_of_items
        
        while i - 2 < number_of_items:
            target_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath\
            ('//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr['\
                 + str(i) + ']/td[2]/a')

            for item in target_data:
                print(item.text, i-1)
                if elements[i - 2] == None:
                    elements[i - 2] = item.text
                elif isinstance(elements[i - 2], list):
                    elements[i - 2].append(item.text)
                else:
                    elements[i - 2] = [elements[i - 2]]
                    elements[i - 2].append(item.text)
            i += 1

        return elements
```

### element.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class BasePageElement():
    """Base page class that is initialized on every page object class."""
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        """Sets the text to the value supplied"""
        driver = obj.driver
        
        text_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element(*self.locator))
        text_field.clear()
        text_field.send_keys(value)
        text_field.submit()

    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        """Gets the text of the specified object"""
        driver = obj.driver
        
        WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda driver: driver.find_element(*self.locator))
        element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)
        return element.get_attribute("value")
```

### locators.py

This is where `split_xpath_at_i` sits.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# import page

class InputLocators():
    """A class for main page locators. All main page locators should come here"""
        
    def dropdown_list_xpath(attribute, value):
        string = "//select[@" + attribute + "='" + value + "']"
        
        return string
    
    MAIN_BODY = (By.XPATH, '//GridTableContent/tbody')
    SEARCH_FIELD = (By.NAME, 'txt_1_value1') # (By.ID, 'search-content-box')
    SEARCH_ATTR = (By.XPATH, dropdown_list_xpath('name', 'txt_1_sel'))
    SEARCH_BUTTON = (By.ID, 'btnSearch')
    NEXT_PAGE = (By.LINK_TEXT, "下頁")

class OutputLocators():
    """A class for search results locators. All search results locators should
    come here"""
    
    def split_xpath_at_i(front_half, back_half):
        # try:
        #     i = page.SearchResults.g_s_elem
        # except:
        #     pass

        if 'i' in locals():
            string = front_half + str(i) + back_half
        else:
            string = front_half+"SPLIT_i"+back_half
    
        return string

    CNKI = {
        "TITLES": (By.XPATH, split_xpath_at_i('//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[', ']/td[2]/a')),
        "AUTHORS": (By.XPATH, split_xpath_at_i('//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[', ']/td[3]/a')),
        "JOURNALS": '//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a',
        "YEAR_ISSUE": '//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/a',
        "DOWNLOAD_PATHS": '//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[1]', 
        "INDEX": (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[2]')
    }


    # # Interim Data
    # CAPTIONS = 
    # LINKS = 
    
    # Target Data
    # TITLES = 
    # AUTHORS = 
    # JOURNALS = 
    # VOL = 
    # ISSUE = 
    # DATES = 
    # DOWNLOAD_PATHS =
```

Comment: Can you include all of your scraping code, or at least a representative sample of HTML that you're trying to parse?

Comment: The whole code consist of a couple `.py` files. Would it be too much to post them here?

Comment: Nope :) The code length limit is quite high, and for the purposes of a question like this, unless the files are perhaps 1000+ lines each, posting them full-form can only help your question.

Comment: Alright, it's done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: I would typically recommend that you replace your use of Selenium with direct `requests` calls. If it's possible, it's way more efficient than Selenium. It would look like the following, as a very rough start:

```
from time import time
from typing import Iterable
from urllib.parse import quote
from requests import Session

def js_encode(u: str) -> Iterable[str]:
    for char in u:
        code = ord(char)
        if code < 128:
            yield quote(char).lower()
        else:
            yield f'%u{code:04x}'


def search(query: str):
    topic = '主题'
    # China Academic Literature Online Publishing Database
    catalog = '中国学术文献网络出版总库'
    databases = (
        '中国期刊全文数据库,'            # China Academic Journals Full-text Database
        '中国博士学位论文全文数据库,'     # China Doctoral Dissertation Full-text Database
        '中国优秀硕士学位论文全文数据库,'  # China Master's Thesis Full-text Database
        '中国重要会议论文全文数据库,'     # China Proceedings of Conference Full-text Database
        '国际会议论文全文数据库,'        # International Proceedings of Conference Full-text Database
        '中国重要报纸全文数据库,'        # China Core Newspapers Full-text Database
        '中国年鉴网络出版总库'          # China Yearbook Full-text Database
    )

    with Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            'Accept':
                'text/html,'
                'application/xhtml+xml,'
                'application/xml;q=0.9,'
                'image/webp,'
                '*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-CA,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'DNT': '1',
            'Host': 'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Sec-GPC': '1',
            'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) '
                'Gecko/20100101 '
                'Firefox/89.0',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        }

        with session.get(
            'https://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/brief/result.aspx',
            params={
                'txt_1_value1': query,
                'txt_1_sel': topic,
                'dbPrefix': 'SCDB',
                'db_opt': catalog,
                'db_value': databases,
                'search-action': 'brief/result.aspx',
            },
        ) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            search_url = response.url
            search_page = response.text

        encoded_query = ''.join(js_encode(',' + query))
        # epoch milliseconds
        timestamp = round(time()*1000)

        # page_params = {
        #     'curpage': 1,
        #     'RecordsPerPage': 20,
        #     'QueryID': 0,
        #     'ID': '',
        #     'turnpage': 1,
        #     'tpagemode': 'L',
        #     'Fields': '',
        #     'DisplayMode': 'listmode',
        #     'sKuaKuID': 0,
        # }

        with session.get(
            'http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/brief/brief.aspx',
            params={
                'pagename': 'ASP.brief_result_aspx',
                'dbPrefix': 'SCDB',
                'dbCatalog': catalog,
                'ConfigFile': 'SCDB.xml',
                'research': 'off',
                't': timestamp,
            },
            cookies={
                'FileNameS': quote('cnki:'),
                'KNS_DisplayModel': '',
                'CurTop10KeyWord': encoded_query,
                'RsPerPage': '20',
            },
            headers={
                'Referer': search_url,
            }
        ) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            results_iframe = response.text


def main():
    etiquette = '禮學'
    search(query=etiquette)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately, the design of this website is violently awful. State is passed around using a mix of query parameters, cookies, and server-only context that you can't see and relies on request history in a non-trivial way. So even though the above produces, to my knowledge, identical parameters, headers and cookies to those that you see in real life on the website, there's a failure where a couple of dynamically-generated `<script>` sections in `brief.aspx` are silently omitted. So I'm giving up on this recommendation.

Shifting gears:

The following recommendations are going to cover scope and class usage, and these should get you toward sanity:

- The code in `test.py` needs to be moved into a function
- Only `test.py` should have a shebang and none of your other files, since only `test.py` is a meaningful entry point.
- Is `Input.URL` ever used? That probably needs to be deleted
- `Input.webpage` should not be returning anything; `driver` is already a member on the class.
- `Input` as a whole is suspect. It provides such a thin wrapper around `driver` as to be basically useless on its own. I would expect the `driver.get()` to be moved to `MainPage.__init__`.
- `InputLocators` also does not deserve to be a class. Those constants can basically be distributed to the point of use, i.e.

  ```
    wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            By.XPATH, 
            '//GridTableContent/tbody',
        )
    )
  ```
- Your `search_keyword` is strange - you start off initializing it as a static, and then change to using it as an instance variable in `submit_search`. Why? Also, what is `keyword`? You would benefit from using PEP484 type hints.
- `switch_to_frame` has timing issues and did not work for me at all until I added two waits:

  ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH,
            '//iframe[@name="iframeResult"]',
        ))
    driver.switch_to.frame('iframeResult')

    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH,
            '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]',
        ))
  ```
- Your `()` at the end of base-less classes can be dropped
- `OutputLocators.CNKI` is a dictionary. Why? `get_single_element` indexes into it, but `get_single_element` is itself never called.

This code:

```
    elements = []
    for item in target_data:
        elements.append(item.text)
    return elements
```

can be replaced with a generator:

```
for item in target_data:
    yield item.text
```

This code:

```
    i = None # get_structured_element counter
```

does nothing since all local variables are discarded at end of scope.

This code:

```
    if 'i' in locals():
        string = front_half + str(i) + back_half
    else:
        string = front_half+"SPLIT_i"+back_half
```

is never going to see its first branch evaluated, since `i` is not defined locally. I really don't know what you intended here.

These long xpath tree traversals, such as

```
'//*[@id="Form1"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a[2]'
```

are both fragile and difficult to read. In most cases you should be able to condense them by a mix of inner `//` to omit parts of the path, and judicious references to known attributes.

You specifically ask about

> `split_xpath_at_i` is blind to variables in its immediate environment

If by "its immediate environment" you mean `CNKI` (etc) that's because its immediate environment, the class static scope, has not yet been initialized. `CNKI` can get a reference to it but not the opposite. If you want this to have some kind of state like a counter, then it needs to be promoted to an instance method with a `self` parameter. I don't know how `g_s_elem` factors into this because it's not defined anywhere.

You ask:

> The SearchTextElement class with just one locator variable that is hardcoded - is that a good approach?

Not really. First of all, you've again conflated static and instance variables, because you first initialize a static variable to `None` and then write an instance variable after construction. Why construct a class at all, if it only holds one member and has no methods?

Comment: I've tried the `requests` call method before, too. It got stuck after submitting the search query. Selenium provides the `driver.switch_to.frame('iframeResult')` to get past that stage and provide access to search result elements. I wonder if there is an equivalent in the `requests` world. What you are describing seems like a different issue altogether.

Comment: I see that you have `results_iframe = response.text` in your sample code as well.

Comment: I suspect the "violently awful" design is a deliberate feature to discourage scraping.

Comment: There are better ways to discourage scraping - I honestly think this is just a product of bad design. For fun, read some of the JS code. It's legacy 12-year-old ASP with a big, crazy mishmash of iframes, AJAX, commented-out code blocks, and developer notes. Bonus points if you can find the comment a developer left confessing to a bad, bad hack. In short, never attribute to malice that which you can attribute to ignorance.

Comment: Can I revise the code and update my question for further review?

Comment: The [Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) implement a locators class as well. (It is called `MainPageLocators`.) Isn't keeping all locators in one place a good design approach?

Comment: The `SearchTextElement` class with just one locator variable that is hardcoded - is that a good approach?

Comment: @Sati Updating your answer is discouraged. However, posting a new question with your incorporated changes are more than welcome

Comment: _Isn't keeping all locators in one place a good design approach?_ If they're reused, perhaps. If they're single use, it's counterproductive - someone following the code will have to branch off to another location to understand what's happening.

Comment: Yeah, I  *do*  intend to reuse the code for other websites.

Comment: OK; but the likelihood that other websites require the same locators is fairly slim, right? Every website's DOM is different. This seems like premature abstraction.