# Use of dataclass when scraping with Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is a follow-up of my last question over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/262883/242934).

Following @Reinderien's [suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263305/242934) in that previous post, I've managed to furnish my web-scraper code as follows:

## fudan.py

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from itertools import count
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session, get
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import os
import re

@dataclass
class Link:
    caption: str
    url: str
    clicks: int
    replies: int
    added: date

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, props: Dict[str, str], url: str) -> 'Link':
        clicks, replies = props['点击/回复'].split('/')
        # Skip number=int(props['编号']) - this only has meaning within one page

        return cls(
            caption=props['资源标题'],
            url=url,
            clicks=int(clicks),
            replies=int(replies),
            added=datetime.strptime(props['添加时间'], '%Y/%m/%d').date().isoformat(),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.added} {self.url} {self.caption}'


# @dataclass
# class Result:
#     author: str
#     title: str
#     date: date
#     download: str
#     publication: str
#     url: str
    

#     @classmethod
#     def from_metadata(cls, metadata: Dict) -> 'Result':
#         author = metadata['author']
#         title = metadata['title']
#         date = metadata['date']
#         download = metadata['download']
#         publication = "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫"
#         url = metadata['url']


#     def __str__(self) -> str:
#         return(
#             f"\n作者 {self.author}"
#             f"\n標題 {self.title}"
#             f"\n發佈日期 {self.date}"
#             f"\n下載連結 {self.download}"
#             f"\n發表平台 {self.publication}"
#             f"\n訪問網頁 {self.url}"
#         )


def get_primary_result():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 
        'primary_search_result.json')

    with open(path, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        data = data.replace('\n][\n',',')
        primary_rslt = json.loads(data)

    return primary_rslt


def get_article():
    primary_rslt = get_primary_result()
    captions_list = [item['caption'] for item in primary_rslt]
    base_url = 'http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn'
    url_list = [base_url + item['url'] for item in primary_rslt]
    date_list = [item['added'] for item in primary_rslt]

    for i, url in enumerate(url_list):

        with get(url) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
            content = doc.select_one('span.ny_font_content')

            category = doc.select('#_top td a')[1].text
            if category == '学者文库':

                try:
                    author, title =  captions_list[i].split("：")
                except:
                    author = None
                    title = captions_list[i]

                if author == "網摘":
                    author = None
                    title = captions_list[i]

                date = date_list[i]
                dl_tag = content.find_all('a', {"href" : 
                    re.compile("/?(lunwen/|articles/up/).+")})[0]
                download = dl_tag['href']
                download = download.replace("\r","").replace("\n", "").strip()

                if download == "#_edn1":
                    download = None
                elif download[0] != "/":
                    download = "/" + download
            
                yield {
                    "author": author, 
                    "title": title, 
                    "date": date, 
                    "url": url, 
                    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
                    "download": download}


def get_page(session: Session, query: str, page: int) -> Tuple[List[Link], int]:
    with session.get(
        'http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Search',
        params={
            's': query,
            'page': page,
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

    table = doc.select_one('#tab table')
    heads = [h.text for h in table.select('tr.cap td')]
    links = []

    for row in table.find_all('tr', class_=''):
        cells = [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')]
        links.append(Link.from_row(
            props=dict(zip(heads, cells)),
            url=row.find('a')['href'],
        ))

    page_td = doc.select_one('#tab table:nth-child(2) td')
    n_pages = int(page_td.text.rsplit('/', 1)[1])

    return links, n_pages


def remove_json_if_exist(filename):
    json_file = filename + ".json"
    filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), json_file)

    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)


def get_all_links(session: Session, query: str) -> Iterable[Link]:

    for page in count(1):
        links, n_pages = get_page(session, query, page)
        print(f'{page}/{n_pages}')
        yield from links

        with open('primary_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump([asdict(link) for link in links], file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        if page >= n_pages:
            break


def search(keyword):
    remove_json_if_exist('primary_search_result')

    with Session() as session:
        for link in get_all_links(session, keyword):
            print(link)
    
    print()


def compile_search_result():
    print("Articles Retrieved:")

    remove_json_if_exist('fudan_search_result')

    rslt = get_article()

    for item in rslt:
        with open('fudan_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump(item, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        
        print(item)


def main():

    search('尹至')
    compile_search_result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code above has the added functionality of looping through the list of urls from the primary search results to yield the metadata of individual articles published on the website.

---

## Output:

```json
{
    "author": "許文獻",
    "title": "重讀清華〈厚父〉簡釋字懸想一則",
    "date": "2018-08-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/4286",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1936重讀清華〈厚父〉簡釋字懸想一則.docx"
}{
    "author": "雷燮仁",
    "title": "談《尚書》中表勉義的幾組字",
    "date": "2017-10-31",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/3152",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1861雷燮仁：談《尚書》中表勉義的幾組字.doc"
}{
    "author": "雷燮仁",
    "title": "誤“埶”為“執”及相關問題考辨",
    "date": "2017-10-31",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/3146",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1855雷燮仁：誤“埶”為“執”及相關問題考辨.doc"
}{
    "author": "蘇建洲",
    "title": "楚系文字“祟”字構形補說兼論相關問題",
    "date": "2017-01-15",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2969",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1731蘇建洲：楚系文字“祟”字構形補說兼論相關問題.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "《周易》“童蒙”解",
    "date": "2016-03-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2767",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1623王寧：《周易》“童蒙”解.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "北大漢簡《蒼頡篇》讀札（下）",
    "date": "2016-03-07",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2747",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1618王寧：北大漢簡《蒼頡篇》讀札（下）.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "讀《殷高宗問於三壽》散札",
    "date": "2015-05-17",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2525",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1479王寧：讀《殷高宗問於三壽》散札.doc"
}{
    "author": "高月",
    "title": "《漢書·藝文志·諸子略》之道家補",
    "date": "2015-05-09",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2516",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1474高月：《漢書·藝文志·諸子略》之道家補.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳劍",
    "title": "《清華簡（伍）》與舊說互證兩則",
    "date": "2015-04-14",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2494",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1454陳劍：《清華簡（伍）》與舊說互證兩則.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "上博二《容成氏》湯伐桀記載辨析",
    "date": "2015-03-11",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2464",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1433王寧：上博二《容成氏》湯伐桀記載辨析.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "上博二《容成氏》“南藻氏”相關問題考論",
    "date": "2015-03-01",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2455",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1425王寧：上博二《容成氏》“南藻氏”相關問題考論.doc"
}{
    "author": "張崇禮",
    "title": "清華簡《尹誥》考釋",
    "date": "2014-12-17",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2400",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1387張崇禮：清華簡《尹誥》考釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "《清華簡〈尹誥〉獻疑》之疑",
    "date": "2014-06-23",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2298",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1337王寧：《清華簡〈尹誥〉獻疑》之疑.doc"
}{
    "author": "孫合肥",
    "title": "清華簡《筮法》札記一則",
    "date": "2014-01-25",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2222",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1300孫合肥：清華簡《筮法》札記一則.doc"
}{
    "author": "陸離",
    "title": "清華簡《別卦》讀“解”之字試說",
    "date": "2014-01-08",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2208",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1292陸離：清華簡《別卦》讀“解”之字試說.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》《赤鳩之集湯之屋》對讀一則",
    "date": "2013-11-28",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2183",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1276王寧：清華簡《尹至》《赤鳩之集湯之屋》對讀一則.doc"
}{
    "author": "呂廟軍",
    "title": "“出土文獻與中國古代文明”國際學術研討會綜述",
    "date": "2013-10-22",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2145",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1254呂廟軍：“出土文獻與中國古代文明”國際學術研討會綜述.doc"
}{
    "author": "王挺斌",
    "title": "清華簡《尹誥》“遠邦歸志”考",
    "date": "2013-06-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2082",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1218王挺斌：清华简《尹诰》“远邦归志”考.doc"
}{
    "author": "高中華",
    "title": "《清華簡》（壹）校讀四則",
    "date": "2013-06-08",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2069",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1208高中华：《清华简》（壹）校读四则.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡《說命上》首句試解",
    "date": "2013-01-21",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2003",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1169陳民鎮：清華簡《說命上》首句試解.doc"
}{
    "author": "劉剛",
    "title": "清華叁《良臣》為具有晉系文字風格的抄本補證",
    "date": "2013-01-17",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/2002",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1168劉剛：清華叁《良臣》為具有晉系文字風格的抄本補證.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳劍",
    "title": "簡談《繫年》的“ ”和楚簡部分“ ”字當釋讀爲“捷””",
    "date": "2013-01-16",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1996",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1167陳劍：簡談《繫年》的“ ”和楚簡部分“ ”字當釋讀爲“捷”.doc"
}{
    "author": "韓祖倫",
    "title": "利用楚簡文字釋讀古璽文字四例",
    "date": "2012-06-05",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1884",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1086韩祖伦：利用楚简文字释读古玺文字四例.doc"
}{
    "author": "蘇建洲",
    "title": "楚竹書的“罝”字",
    "date": "2012-04-13",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1844",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1057蘇建洲：楚竹書的“罝”字.doc"
}{
    "author": "苗豐",
    "title": "卜辭“中录”補證",
    "date": "2012-03-25",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1809",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1049苗豐：卜辭“中录”補證.doc"
}{
    "author": "張世超",
    "title": "佔畢脞說（八）",
    "date": "2012-03-09",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1800",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1040張世超：佔畢脞說（八）.doc"
}{
    "author": "張世超",
    "title": "佔畢脞說（三、四）",
    "date": "2012-02-23",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1787",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1029張世超：佔畢脞說（三、四）.doc"
}{
    "author": "張崇禮",
    "title": "釋清華簡《尹至》的“瓚”字",
    "date": "2011-12-23",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1748",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/1001張崇禮：釋清華簡《尹至》的“瓚”字.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡《楚居》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-23",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1663",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0951陳民鎮：清華簡《楚居》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "胡凱",
    "title": "清華簡《祭公之顧命》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-23",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1662",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0950胡凱：清華簡《祭公之顧命》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "汪亞洲",
    "title": "清華簡《皇門》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-23",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1660",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0949汪亞洲：清華簡《皇門》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳民鎮、胡凱",
    "title": "清華簡《金縢》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-20",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1658",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0947陳民鎮、胡凱：清華簡《金縢》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "顏偉明、陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡《耆夜》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-20",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1657",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0946顏偉明、陳民鎮：清華簡《耆夜》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "胡凱、陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡《保訓》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-19",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1654",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0943陳民鎮、胡凱：清華簡《保訓》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "禚孝文",
    "title": "清華簡《程寤》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-17",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1653",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0942禚孝文：清華簡《程寤》集释.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡《尹誥》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-12",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1648",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0938陳民鎮：清華簡《尹誥》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-12",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1647",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0937陳民鎮：清華簡《尹至》集釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "汪亞洲、陳民鎮",
    "title": "清華簡研究論著目錄簡編",
    "date": "2011-09-12",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1646",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0936汪亞洲、陳民鎮：清華簡研究論著目錄簡編.doc"
}{
    "author": "劉信芳",
    "title": "清華藏簡（壹）試讀",
    "date": "2011-09-09",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1643",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0934劉信芳：清華藏簡（壹）試讀.doc"
}{
    "author": "鄧少平",
    "title": "清華簡研究論著目錄（2008.12—2011.8）",
    "date": "2011-08-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1631",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0928鄧少平：清華簡研究論著目錄.doc"
}{
    "author": "汪亞洲",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》“亡典”說",
    "date": "2011-06-17",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1556",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/lunwen/0882汪亞洲：清華簡《尹至》“亡典”說.doc"
}{
    "author": null,
    "title": "網摘：2011年3月",
    "date": "2011-05-02",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1485",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0855網摘：2011年3月.doc"
}{
    "author": "劉光勝",
    "title": "清華簡《耆夜》考論",
    "date": "2011-04-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1484",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0854刘光胜：清华简耆夜新探.doc"
}{
    "author": "劉洪濤",
    "title": "清華簡補釋四則",
    "date": "2011-04-27",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1479",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0851刘洪涛：清华简补释四则.doc"
}{
    "author": "蘇建洲",
    "title": "論楚竹書“厇”字構形",
    "date": "2011-04-10",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1459",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0838蘇建洲：論楚竹書“厇”字構形.doc"
}{
    "author": null,
    "title": "網摘：2011年2月",
    "date": "2011-04-02",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1450",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0830網摘：2011年2月.doc"
}{
    "author": "劉波",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》“僮亡典”補說",
    "date": "2011-03-04",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1421",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0812清華簡《尹至》“僮亡典”補說.doc"
}{
    "author": null,
    "title": "網摘：2011年1月",
    "date": "2011-03-01",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1417",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0809網摘：2011年1月.doc"
}{
    "author": "陳劍",
    "title": "清華簡《皇門》“賏爾”字補說",
    "date": "2011-02-04",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1397",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0803清華簡《皇門》“賏爾”字補說.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》《尹誥》中的“衆”和“民”",
    "date": "2011-02-04",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1396",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0802清華簡《尹至》《尹誥》中的“衆”與“民”.doc"
}{
    "author": null,
    "title": "網摘：《清華一》專輯",
    "date": "2011-02-02",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1393",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0799網摘《清華一》專輯.doc"
}{
    "author": "王寧",
    "title": "讀清華簡《程寤》偶記一則",
    "date": "2011-01-28",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1389",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0797讀清華簡《程寤》偶記一則.doc"
}{
    "author": "蕭旭",
    "title": "清華竹簡《程寤》校補",
    "date": "2011-01-13",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1379",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0793清華竹簡《程寤》校補.doc"
}{
    "author": "袁瑩",
    "title": "清華簡《程寤》校讀",
    "date": "2011-01-11",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1376",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0790清華簡《程寤》校讀.doc"
}{
    "author": "孫飛燕",
    "title": "試論《尹至》的“至在湯”與《尹誥》的“及湯”",
    "date": "2011-01-10",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1373",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0788試論《尹至》的“至在湯”與《尹誥》的“及湯”.doc"
}{
    "author": "蘇建洲",
    "title": "《清華簡》考釋四則",
    "date": "2011-01-09",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1368",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0784《清華簡》考釋四則.doc"
}{
    "author": "沈培",
    "title": "清華簡字詞考釋二則",
    "date": "2011-01-09",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1367",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0783清華簡字詞考釋二則.doc"
}{
    "author": "讀書會",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》、《尹誥》研讀札記",
    "date": "2011-01-05",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1352",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0774清華簡《尹至》、《尹誥》研讀札記.doc"
}{
    "author": "讀書會",
    "title": "清華簡《耆夜》研讀札記",
    "date": "2011-01-05",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1347",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0773清華簡《耆夜》研讀札記.doc"
}{
    "author": "朱曉海",
    "title": "〈尹至〉可能是百篇《尚書》中前所未見的一篇",
    "date": "2010-06-17",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1187",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0692〈尹至〉可能是百篇《尚書》中前所未見的一篇.doc"
}{
    "author": null,
    "title": "清華九簡研讀札記",
    "date": "2010-05-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1166",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0676清華九簡研讀札記.doc"
}{
    "author": "蘇建洲",
    "title": "《清華簡九篇綜述》封二所刊《皇門》簡簡釋",
    "date": "2010-05-30",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/1165",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0675《清華簡九篇綜述》封二所刊《皇門》簡簡釋.doc"
}{
    "author": "淺野裕一",
    "title": "上博楚簡《柬大王泊旱》之災異思想",
    "date": "2009-09-13",
    "url": "http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Show/904",
    "publication": "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫",
    "download": "/articles/up/0494上博楚簡《柬大王泊旱》之災異思想.doc"
}
```

## Questions:

I originally intended to use another `dataclass` (as commented out) to extend @Reinderien's answer, but ended up doing the whole thing with functions and dictionaries instead.

So my main question would be:

1. How do we decide whether a `dataclass` is necessary for a task?
2. Something specific to this part the `get_page` function in `fudan.py` above:

```py
with session.get(
        'http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Search',
        params={
            's': query,
            'page': page,
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
```

Why can't (or shouldn't) we just use this instead?

```py
from requests import get
with get('http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn/Web/Search?s=' + query) as resp:
...
```

(*Points of concern*: ① difference between `get` and `session.get` ② use of `params` instead of posting the query directly as part of the url string)

3. Any other suggestion to improve my code are also welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Distinguish between your Link and Result classes; I've renamed the latter to Article
- Publication is the same for every row so I've omitted it. You can reintroduce it if you really want, but it's strange to have to hard-code a value that's the same for every record in a file.
- Having an intermediate JSON that's saved only to be loaded again is not a good idea. Just operate on values in memory. The traditional thing to do may be to load the entire intermediate data to a list and then iterate over it, but that doesn't scale well in memory. The approach I've shown is wholly iterative and only carries one page at a time in memory.
- Deleting and then opening a file in append mode doesn't make sense. Just open it in normal write mode, and it will truncate and overwrite any existing contents.
- Never bare `try/except`. In this case since you're looking for a separator, just test for existence of the separator instead of using logic-by-exception.
- You broke the `date`-typed column that I suggested by storing it as a string. Don't format it to a string until it reaches the edge of your program.
- `get_all_links` is not the right place to save to JSON.
- Your category filter does not need to hard-code an index to a specific anchor. Instead look for `#` in the `href`.

Your specific points of concern:

> difference between get and session.get

You already have a session, that you use half of the time - the other half you're doing direct `get`, which in this context you should avoid. Just use the session. It better expresses your intent to (1) carry around any potential cookies that a browser would, (2) apply common headers if that ever becomes necessary, and (3) share a connection pool.

> use of params instead of posting the query directly as part of the url string

The `params` dict is a more Pythonic way of passing parameters: key-value pairs are manipulated more easily, you can pass in non-string parameters that Requests will coerce to strings for you, and Requests will do all of the necessary encoding and escaping that you shouldn't have to care about yourself.

> How do we decide whether a dataclass is necessary for a task?

Nothing is ever "necessary", but dataclasses are often "well-suited". Consider if:

- You're using Python 3.7+, which you should be anyway
- You know the attributes of the class and their types, which you should anyway
- The general-purpose constructor `__init__` would be a trivial assignment of parameters to members
- Any specific-purpose pseudoconstructors can be represented as `@classmethod`s returning a class instance or instances

then dataclasses are well-suited.

### Suggested

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import count
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List, Optional
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import re

BASE_URL = 'http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn'


@dataclass
class Link:
    caption: str
    url: str
    clicks: int
    replies: int
    added: date

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, props: Dict[str, str], path: str) -> 'Link':
        clicks, replies = props['点击/回复'].split('/')
        # Skip number=int(props['编号']) - this only has meaning within one page

        return cls(
            caption=props['资源标题'],
            url=urljoin(BASE_URL, path),
            clicks=int(clicks),
            replies=int(replies),
            added=datetime.strptime(props['添加时间'], '%Y/%m/%d').date(),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.added} {self.url} {self.caption}'

    def author_title(self) -> Tuple[Optional[str], str]:
        sep = '：'  # full-width colon, U+FF1A

        if sep not in self.caption:
            return None, self.caption

        author, title = self.caption.split(sep, 1)
        author, title = author.strip(), title.strip()

        net_digest = '網摘'
        if author == net_digest:
            return None, title

        return author, title


@dataclass
class Article:
    author: Optional[str]
    title: str
    date: date
    download: Optional[str]
    url: str

    @classmethod
    def from_link(cls, link: Link, download: str) -> 'Article':

        author, title = link.author_title()

        download = download.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").strip()
        if download == '#_edn1':
            download = None
        elif download[0] != '/':
            download = '/' + download

        return cls(
            author=author,
            title=title,
            date=link.added,
            download=download,
            url=link.url,
        )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return(
            f"\n作者   {self.author}"
            f"\n標題   {self.title}"
            f"\n發佈日期 {self.date}"
            f"\n下載連結 {self.download}"
            f"\n訪問網頁 {self.url}"
        )

    def as_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
            'author': self.author,
            'title': self.title,
            'date': self.date.isoformat(),
            'download': self.download,
            'url': self.url,
        }


def compile_search_results(session: Session, links: Iterable[Link], category_filter: str) -> Iterable[Article]:

    for link in links:
        with session.get(link.url) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

        category = doc.select_one('#_top td a[href="#"]').text
        if category != category_filter:
            continue

        content = doc.select_one('span.ny_font_content')
        dl_tag = content.find(
            'a', {
                'href': re.compile("/?(lunwen/|articles/up/).+")
            }
        )

        yield Article.from_link(link, download=dl_tag['href'])


def get_page(session: Session, query: str, page: int) -> Tuple[List[Link], int]:
    with session.get(
        urljoin(BASE_URL, '/Web/Search'),
        params={
            's': query,
            'page': page,
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

    table = doc.select_one('#tab table')
    heads = [h.text for h in table.select('tr.cap td')]
    links = []

    for row in table.find_all('tr', class_=''):
        cells = [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')]
        links.append(Link.from_row(
            props=dict(zip(heads, cells)),
            path=row.find('a')['href'],
        ))

    page_td = doc.select_one('#tab table:nth-child(2) td')
    n_pages = int(page_td.text.rsplit('/', 1)[1])

    return links, n_pages


def get_all_links(session: Session, query: str) -> Iterable[Link]:
    for page in count(1):
        links, n_pages = get_page(session, query, page)
        print(f'{page}/{n_pages}')
        yield from links

        if page >= n_pages:
            break


def save_articles(articles: Iterable[Article], file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def main():
    with Session() as session:
        links = get_all_links(session, query='尹至')
        academic_library = '学者文库'
        articles = compile_search_results(session, links, category_filter=academic_library)
        save_articles(articles, 'fudan_search_result')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```