# requests vs selenium vs scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is a follow-up of my question over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/262883/242934).

I have been working on my web-scraping techniques by trying out different approaches and rewriting code for a handful of online databases.

I've recently seen for myself that `requests` is definitely way more efficient than `selenium`, as demonstrated by the scripts below. `requests` retrieved far more data in a much shorter time than `selenium`.

Differences in output is (most likely) due to application of the search keyword in content (`按文章內容`) filter on the website with `selenium`.

Another popular web-scraping framework in Python is [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org).

## Questions:

1. How would the code look like with that method?
2. How does `Scrapy` compare to the other two above?
3. Assuming a developer has equivalent high-level proficiency for each method, how does he/she decide when to use which method for a given task? In other words, what are the factors determining the method that is most suited to the task?
4. Any suggestions to improve on the existing code are also welcome!

---

## wuhan.py

### By Requests:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from itertools import count
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import post
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import os
import re

@dataclass
class Result:
    author: str
    title: str
    date: date
    url: str
    publication: str = "武漢大學簡帛網"

    @classmethod
    def from_metadata(cls, metadata: Dict) -> 'Result': 
        author, title = metadata['caption'].split('：')
        published_date = date.isoformat(datetime.strptime(metadata['date'], '%y/%m/%d'))
        url = 'http://www.bsm.org.cn/' + metadata['url']

        return cls(
            author = author,
            title = title,
            date = published_date,
            url = url
        )


    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'作者　　　　{self.author}'
            f'\n標題     {self.title}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n文章連結　{self.url}'
            f'\n發表平台  {self.publication}'
        )


def submit_query(keyword: str):
    query = {"searchword": keyword}
    with post('http://www.bsm.org.cn/pages.php?pagename=search', query) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
        content = doc.find('div', class_='record_list_main')
        rows = content.select('ul')


    for row in rows:
        if len(row.findAll('li')) != 2:
            print()
            print(row.text)
            print()
        else:
            captions_tag, date_tag = row.findAll('li')
            caption_anchors = captions_tag.findAll('a')
            category, caption = [item.text for item in caption_anchors]
            url = caption_anchors[1]['href']
            date = re.sub("[()]", "", date_tag.text)

            yield {
                "category": category, 
                "caption": caption, 
                "date": date,
                "url": url}


def remove_json_if_exists(filename):
    json_file = filename + ".json"
    filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), json_file)

    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)


def search(query: str):
    remove_json_if_exists('wuhan_search_result')
    rslt = submit_query(query)

    for metadata in rslt:
        article = Result.from_metadata(metadata)
        print(article)
        print()

        with open('wuhan_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump(asdict(article), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)


def main():

    search('尹至')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Output:

```json
{
    "author": "楊 坤 ",
    "title": "說清華竹書《尹至》“白[夕彔]”",
    "date": "2015-12-28",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2408",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "馬文增 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》新釋、注解、白話譯文",
    "date": "2015-06-01",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2246",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "楊 坤 ",
    "title": "跋清華竹書《尹至》",
    "date": "2013-09-16",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1902",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》“勞”字臆解",
    "date": "2012-07-31",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1724",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "沈亞丹、王云飛 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》、《尹誥》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-27",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1556",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "邢 文 ",
    "title": "談清華簡《尹至》的“動亡典，夏有祥”",
    "date": "2011-03-25",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1423",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃懷信 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》補釋",
    "date": "2011-03-17",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1416",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》釋證四例",
    "date": "2011-02-21",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1403",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃人二、趙思木 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》餘釋",
    "date": "2011-01-12",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1385",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃人二、趙思木 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》補釋",
    "date": "2011-01-11",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1383",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "趙平安、王挺斌 ",
    "title": "論清華簡的文獻學價值",
    "date": "2019-05-07",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=3361",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "清華簡七《子犯子餘》文字釋讀二則",
    "date": "2017-05-03",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2798",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "清華簡《說命》補釋五則",
    "date": "2016-02-19",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2472",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "楊 坤 ",
    "title": "說清華竹書《尹至》“白[夕彔]”",
    "date": "2015-12-28",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2408",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "龐壯城 ",
    "title": "北大漢簡《節》考釋零箋",
    "date": "2015-11-25",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2374",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "馬文增 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹誥》新釋、簡注、白話譯文",
    "date": "2015-06-08",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2256",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "馬文增 ",
    "title": "據“清華簡”看關於伊尹的訛傳與誤解",
    "date": "2015-06-04",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2250",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "馬文增 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》新釋、注解、白話譯文",
    "date": "2015-06-01",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2246",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "上博二《容成氏》戎遂、鬲山氏、鳴條考",
    "date": "2015-02-27",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2162",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "潘 潤 ",
    "title": "從清華簡《繫年》看戴氏取宋的開始時間及其歷史意義",
    "date": "2014-12-06",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2106",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "釋郭店簡《老子》乙中的“劬”",
    "date": "2014-11-12",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2102",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "許名瑲 ",
    "title": "戰國簡帛總括範圍副詞“畢”、“率”探究",
    "date": "2013-12-28",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1971",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "許名瑲 ",
    "title": "戰國簡帛總括範圍副詞“咸”探究",
    "date": "2013-12-17",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1965",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "許名瑲 ",
    "title": "戰國簡帛總括範圍副詞“皆”探究",
    "date": "2013-11-27",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1957",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "楊 坤 ",
    "title": "跋清華竹書《尹至》",
    "date": "2013-09-16",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1902",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃庭頎 ",
    "title": "論古文字材料所見之「伊尹」稱號",
    "date": "2013-07-15",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1866",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "肖芸曉 ",
    "title": "試論清華竹書伊尹三篇的關聯",
    "date": "2013-03-07",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1834",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "楊 博 ",
    "title": "簡述楚系簡帛典籍的史料分類",
    "date": "2013-01-17",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1819",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》“勞”字臆解",
    "date": "2012-07-31",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1724",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "申 超 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹誥》“我克協我友,今惟民遠邦歸志”試說",
    "date": "2012-04-20",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1672",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "張 峰 ",
    "title": "《清華簡〈程寤〉》中的“思”",
    "date": "2011-11-11",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1576",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王玉蛟 ",
    "title": "淺論《清華簡（一）》中的“于”和“於”",
    "date": "2011-11-03",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1574",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王玉蛟 ",
    "title": "《清華簡大學藏戰國竹簡（壹）》人稱代詞研究",
    "date": "2011-11-02",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1573",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃尚明 ",
    "title": "從楚簡證“《詩》、《書》、執禮”的“執”應讀爲“埶”",
    "date": "2011-10-14",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1563",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "沈亞丹、王云飛 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》、《尹誥》集釋",
    "date": "2011-09-27",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1556",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "李燁、田佳鷺 ",
    "title": "“清華簡（壹）”中的“厥”和“其”",
    "date": "2011-06-17",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1495",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "邢 文 ",
    "title": "談清華簡《尹至》的“動亡典，夏有祥”",
    "date": "2011-03-25",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1423",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃懷信 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》補釋",
    "date": "2011-03-17",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1416",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "王 寧 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》釋證四例",
    "date": "2011-02-21",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1403",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃人二、趙思木 ",
    "title": "讀《清華大學藏戰國竹簡（壹）》..",
    "date": "2011-02-17",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1402",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "曹方向 ",
    "title": "記清華簡第一冊九篇竹書的若干書寫情況",
    "date": "2011-01-31",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1396",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃 杰 ",
    "title": "清華簡《程寤》筆記一則",
    "date": "2011-01-12",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1387",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃人二、趙思木 ",
    "title": "清華簡《尹至》補釋",
    "date": "2011-01-11",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1383",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "宋華强 ",
    "title": "清華簡校讀散札",
    "date": "2011-01-10",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1380",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃 杰 ",
    "title": "讀清華簡筆記（二）",
    "date": "2011-01-09",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1376",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃人二、趙思木 ",
    "title": "讀《清華大學藏戰國竹簡（壹）》..",
    "date": "2011-01-09",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1375",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "曹方向 ",
    "title": "清華大學藏戰國竹簡《尹誥》篇補議一則",
    "date": "2011-01-08",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1373",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "何有祖 ",
    "title": "清華大學藏簡讀札（一）",
    "date": "2011-01-08",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1372",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}{
    "author": "黃人二、趙思木 ",
    "title": "讀《清華大學藏戰國竹簡》書後（..",
    "date": "2011-01-07",
    "url": "http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1368",
    "publication": "武漢大學簡帛網"
}
```

---

### By Selenium:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass, replace
from datetime import datetime, date
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Optional, ContextManager
import re
import time

# pip install proxy.py
import proxy
from proxy.http.exception import HttpRequestRejected
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
    TimeoutException,
    WebDriverException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


@dataclass
class PrimaryResult:
    caption: str
    date: date
    link: str

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: WebElement) -> 'PrimaryResult': 

        caption_elems, date_elems = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
        captions = caption_elems.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[1]
        date_elems = re.sub("[()]", "", date_elems.text)
        published_date = date.isoformat(datetime.strptime(date_elems, '%y/%m/%d'))

        return cls(
            caption = captions.text,
            date = published_date,
            link = captions.get_attribute('href')
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'標題      {self.caption}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n文章連結　{self.link}'
        )


class MainPage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver


    def select_dropdown_item(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form/li[2]/select/option[text()='按文章內容']").click()


    def submit_search(self, keyword: str) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)
        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'searchword'))
        )
        search.send_keys(keyword)
        search.submit()


    def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
        elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        return elm

    def next_page(self) -> None:
        try: 
            link = self.get_element_and_stop_page(By.LINK_TEXT, "下页")
        except:
            print("No button with 「下页」 found.")
            return

        try:
            link.click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")
        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("Last page reached")

    # @contextmanager
    # def wait_for_new_window(self):
    #     driver = self.driver
    #     handles_before = driver.window_handles
    #     yield
    #     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #         lambda driver: len(handles_before) != len(driver.window_handles))

    def switch_tabs(self):
        driver = self.driver
        print("Current Window:")
        print(driver.title)
        print()

        p = driver.current_window_handle
        
        chwd = driver.window_handles
        time.sleep(3)
        """
         I am not quite sure how to use `wait.until...` in this context, 
         so I make do with `time.sleep(3)` before switching windows.
        """
        driver.switch_to.window(chwd[1])

        print("New Window:")
        print(driver.title)
        print()


class SearchResults:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_structured_elements(self):
        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[5]/div[2]/div/ul[position() > 1]')
        # caption_links = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[5]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a[2]')

        # if :
        #     for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        #         if "發表的文章有" not in row.text:
        #             pass
        #         else:
        #             slice = i+1

        #     rows = rows[slice:]

        for row in rows:
            yield PrimaryResult.from_row(row)




# class ContentFilterPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
#     HOST_WHITELIST = {
#         b'ocsp.digicert.com',
#         b'ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com',
#         b'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
#         b'gwz.fudan.edu.cn'
#     }

#     def handle_client_request(self, request: HttpParser) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
#         host = request.host or request.header(b'Host')
#         if host not in self.HOST_WHITELIST:
#             raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

#         if any(
#             suffix in request.path
#             for suffix in (
#                 b'png', b'ico', b'jpg', b'gif', b'css',
#             )
#         ):
#             raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

#         return request

#     def before_upstream_connection(self, request):
#         return super().before_upstream_connection(request)
#     def handle_upstream_chunk(self, chunk):
#         return super().handle_upstream_chunk(chunk)
#     def on_upstream_connection_close(self):
#         pass


# @contextmanager
# def run_driver() -> ContextManager[WebDriver]:
#     prox_type = ProxyType.MANUAL['ff_value']
#     prox_host = '127.0.0.1'
#     prox_port = 8889

#     profile = FirefoxProfile()
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', prox_type)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', prox_host)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', prox_host)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', prox_port)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', prox_port)
#     profile.update_preferences()

#     plugin = f'{Path(__file__).stem}.{ContentFilterPlugin.__name__}'

#     with proxy.start((
#         '--hostname', prox_host,
#         '--port', str(prox_port),
#         '--plugins', plugin,
#     )), Firefox(profile) as driver:
#         yield driver


def search(keyword) -> None:
    with Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get('http://www.bsm.org.cn/index.php')

        page = MainPage(driver)
        page.select_dropdown_item()
        page.submit_search(keyword)

        time.sleep(5)
        page.switch_tabs()

        primary_result_page = SearchResults(driver)
        primary_results = primary_result_page.get_structured_elements()
        for result in primary_results:
            print(result)
            print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

#### Output:

```
Current Window:
簡帛網-武漢大學簡帛研究中心
New Window:
簡帛網》搜索

標題      趙平安、王挺斌 ：論清華簡的文獻學價值
發表時間  2019-05-07
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=3361


標題      王 寧 ：清華簡七《子犯子餘》文字釋讀二則
發表時間  2017-05-03
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2798


標題      王 寧 ：清華簡《說命》補釋五則
發表時間  2016-02-19
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2472


標題      楊 坤 ：說清華竹書《尹至》“白[夕彔]”
發表時間  2015-12-28
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2408


標題      龐壯城 ：北大漢簡《節》考釋零箋
發表時間  2015-11-25
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2374


標題      馬文增 ：清華簡《尹誥》新釋、簡注、白話譯文
發表時間  2015-06-08
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2256


標題      馬文增 ：據“清華簡”看關於伊尹的訛傳與誤解
發表時間  2015-06-04
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2250


標題      馬文增 ：清華簡《尹至》新釋、注解、白話譯文
發表時間  2015-06-01
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2246


標題      王 寧 ：上博二《容成氏》戎遂、鬲山氏、鳴條考
發表時間  2015-02-27
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2162


標題      潘 潤 ：從清華簡《繫年》看戴氏取宋的開始時間及其歷史意義
發表時間  2014-12-06
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2106


標題      王 寧 ：釋郭店簡《老子》乙中的“劬”
發表時間  2014-11-12
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=2102


標題      許名瑲 ：戰國簡帛總括範圍副詞“畢”、“率”探究
發表時間  2013-12-28
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1971


標題      許名瑲 ：戰國簡帛總括範圍副詞“咸”探究
發表時間  2013-12-17
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1965


標題      許名瑲 ：戰國簡帛總括範圍副詞“皆”探究
發表時間  2013-11-27
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1957


標題      楊 坤 ：跋清華竹書《尹至》
發表時間  2013-09-16
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1902


標題      黃庭頎 ：論古文字材料所見之「伊尹」稱號
發表時間  2013-07-15
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1866


標題      肖芸曉 ：試論清華竹書伊尹三篇的關聯
發表時間  2013-03-07
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1834


標題      楊 博 ：簡述楚系簡帛典籍的史料分類
發表時間  2013-01-17
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1819


標題      王 寧 ：清華簡《尹至》“勞”字臆解
發表時間  2012-07-31
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1724


標題      申 超 ：清華簡《尹誥》“我克協我友,今惟民遠邦歸志”試說
發表時間  2012-04-20
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1672


標題      張 峰 ：《清華簡〈程寤〉》中的“思”
發表時間  2011-11-11
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1576


標題      王玉蛟 ：淺論《清華簡（一）》中的“于”和“於”
發表時間  2011-11-03
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1574


標題      王玉蛟 ：《清華簡大學藏戰國竹簡（壹）》人稱代詞研究
發表時間  2011-11-02
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1573


標題      黃尚明 ：從楚簡證“《詩》、《書》、執禮”的“執”應讀爲“埶”
發表時間  2011-10-14
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1563


標題      沈亞丹、王云飛 ：清華簡《尹至》、《尹誥》集釋
發表時間  2011-09-27
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1556


標題      李燁、田佳鷺 ：“清華簡（壹）”中的“厥”和“其”
發表時間  2011-06-17
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1495


標題      邢 文 ：談清華簡《尹至》的“動亡典，夏有祥”
發表時間  2011-03-25
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1423


標題      黃懷信 ：清華簡《尹至》補釋
發表時間  2011-03-17
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1416


標題      王 寧 ：清華簡《尹至》釋證四例
發表時間  2011-02-21
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1403


標題      黃人二、趙思木 ：讀《清華大學藏戰國竹簡（壹）》..
發表時間  2011-02-17
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1402


標題      曹方向 ：記清華簡第一冊九篇竹書的若干書寫情況
發表時間  2011-01-31
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1396


標題      黃 杰 ：清華簡《程寤》筆記一則
發表時間  2011-01-12
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1387


標題      黃人二、趙思木 ：清華簡《尹至》補釋
發表時間  2011-01-11
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1383


標題      宋華强 ：清華簡校讀散札
發表時間  2011-01-10
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1380


標題      黃 杰 ：讀清華簡筆記（二）
發表時間  2011-01-09
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1376


標題      黃人二、趙思木 ：讀《清華大學藏戰國竹簡（壹）》..
發表時間  2011-01-09
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1375


標題      曹方向 ：清華大學藏戰國竹簡《尹誥》篇補議一則
發表時間  2011-01-08
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1373


標題      何有祖 ：清華大學藏簡讀札（一）
發表時間  2011-01-08
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1372


標題      黃人二、趙思木 ：讀《清華大學藏戰國竹簡》書後（..
發表時間  2011-01-07
文章連結　http://www.bsm.org.cn/show_article.php?id=1368
```

---