# Scraping a dynamic website with Scrapy (or Requests) and Selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy for one of the sites I've scraped before using Selenium over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/263373/requests-vs-selenium-vs-scrapy).

Because the search field for this site is dynamically generated and requires the user to hover the cursor over a button before it appears, I can't seem to find a way to POST the query using `Requests` or Scrapy's spider alone.

In `scrapy shell`, though I can:

```py
fetch(FormRequest.from_response(response, 
                                formdata={'.search-left input':"尹至"}, 
                                callback=self.search_result))
```

I have no way to tell whether the search query is successful or not.

Here is a simple *working code* which I will be using for my spider below.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

            
def parse(url):
    with Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
        xpath = "//form/button/input"
        element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
        hover.perform()
        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'showkeycode1015273'))
        )
        search.send_keys("尹至")
        search.submit()

        time.sleep(5)
        
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search_list > li")

        for row in rows:
            caption_elems = row.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            yield {
                    "caption" : caption_elems.text,
                    "date": row.find_element_by_class_name('time').text,
                    "url": caption_elems.get_attribute('href')
                    }


x = parse('https://www.ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn')

for rslt in x:
    print(rslt)
```

The scrapy spider below stops short at entering the search query when I run `scrapy crawl qinghua`.

```py
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class QinghuaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'qinghua'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        with Firefox() as driver:
            driver.get(response.url)
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)

            xpath = "//form/button/input"
            element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
            hover.perform()

            search = wait.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'showkeycode1015273'))
            )
            search.send_keys("尹至")
            search.submit()

            time.sleep(5)

            rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search_list > li")
            
            for row in rows:
                caption_elems = row.find_element_by_tag_name('a')

                yield {
                        "caption" : caption_elems.text,
                        "date": row.find_element_by_class_name('time').text,
                        "url": caption_elems.get_attribute('href')
                        }

#             return FormRequest.from_response(
#                    response, 
#                    formdata={'.search-left input':"尹至"}, 
#                    callback=self.search_result)



    def search_result(self, response):
        pass
```

I would like to ask:

1. Why the spider code doesn't work, and
2. How to do this properly in Scrapy, with or (preferably) without the help of Selenium.

I suspect this website has a robust anti-bot infrastructure that can prevent spiders from operating properly.

Comment: I think for this to be on topic, you're going to need to excise the part that doesn't work.

Comment: @Heslacher: No. I did not update any code in my question. I merely provided extra information to point out where the present answer is lacking.

Comment: I would agree to a rollback of the title if that is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Oh, wow, sorry I just saw "The suggested code given by Reinderien below, though it produced an output, did not actually capture the keyword." and didn't check what you actually added. Sorry for that.

Comment: Agreed.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the search field for this site is dynamically generated

That doesn't matter, since - if you bypass the UI - the form field name itself is not dynamic. Even if you were to keep using Selenium, it should be possible to write an element selector that does not need to rely on the dynamic attributes of the search field.

> Why the spider code doesn't work

Non-working code is off-topic, so I'm ignoring that part.

> I suspect this website has a robust anti-bot infrastructure that can prevent spiders from operating properly.

It actually doesn't (thankfully); and my prior difficulties were due to a silly error on my part omitting some form entries. This doesn't need to manipulate headers or cookies, or even fill in a fake user agent.

So in terms of review, the usual: use Requests if you can; improve your type safety; avoid dictionaries for internal data.

### Suggested

```
from base64 import b64encode
from datetime import date
from typing import Iterable, ClassVar

from attr import dataclass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer, Tag
from requests import Session


@dataclass
class Result:
    caption: str
    when: date
    path: str

    @classmethod
    def from_list_item(cls, item: Tag) -> 'Result':
        return cls(
            caption=item.a.text,
            path=item.a['href'],
            when=date.fromisoformat(item.find('span', recursive=False).text),
        )


class TsinghuaSite:
    subdoc: ClassVar[SoupStrainer] = SoupStrainer(name='ul', class_='search_list')

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()

    def __enter__(self) -> 'TsinghuaSite':
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.session.close()

    def search(self, query: str) -> Iterable[Result]:
        with self.session.post(
            'https://www.ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn/search.jsp',
            params={'wbtreeid': 1001},
            data={
                'lucenenewssearchkey': b64encode(query.encode()),
                '_lucenesearchtype': '1',
                'searchScope': '0',
                'x': '0',
                'y': '0',
            },
        ) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(markup=resp.text, features='html.parser', parse_only=self.subdoc)

        for item in doc.find('ul', recursive=False).find_all('li', recursive=False):
            yield Result.from_list_item(item)


def main():
    with TsinghuaSite() as site:
        query = '尹至'
        results = tuple(site.search(query))

    assert any(query in r.caption for r in results)
    for result in results:
        print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
Result(caption='出土文献研究与保护中心2020年报', when=datetime.date(2021, 4, 9), path='info/1041/2615.htm')
Result(caption='《战国秦汉文字与文献论稿》出版', when=datetime.date(2020, 7, 17), path='info/1012/1289.htm')
Result(caption='【光明日报】清华简十年：古书重现与古史新探', when=datetime.date(2018, 12, 25), path='info/1072/1551.htm')
Result(caption='《清華簡與古史探賾》出版', when=datetime.date(2018, 8, 30), path='info/1012/1436.htm')
Result(caption='【出土文獻第九輯】鄔可晶：《尹至》“惟（肉哉）虐德暴（身童）亡典”句試解', when=datetime.date(2018, 5, 24), path='info/1073/1952.htm')
Result(caption='【出土文獻第五輯】袁金平：從《尹至》篇“播”字的討論談文義對文字考釋的重要性', when=datetime.date(2018, 4, 26), path='info/1081/2378.htm')
Result(caption='【出土文獻第五輯】袁金平：從《尹至》篇“播”字的討論談文義對文字考釋的重要性', when=datetime.date(2018, 4, 26), path='info/1081/2378.htm')
Result(caption='【出土文獻第二輯】羅   琨：讀《尹至》“自夏徂亳”', when=datetime.date(2018, 4, 12), path='info/1081/2283.htm')
Result(caption='【出土文獻第二輯】羅   琨：讀《尹至》“自夏徂亳”', when=datetime.date(2018, 4, 12), path='info/1081/2283.htm')
Result(caption='《出土文獻》（第九輯）出版', when=datetime.date(2016, 10, 26), path='info/1012/1411.htm')
Result(caption='《出土文獻研究》第十三輯出版', when=datetime.date(2015, 4, 8), path='info/1012/1396.htm')
Result(caption='清華大學藏戰國竹簡第五冊相關研究論文', when=datetime.date(2015, 4, 8), path='info/1081/2215.htm')
Result(caption='清華大學藏戰國竹簡第五冊相關研究論文', when=datetime.date(2015, 4, 8), path='info/1081/2215.htm')
Result(caption='《出土文獻》（第五輯）出版', when=datetime.date(2014, 10, 13), path='info/1012/1393.htm')
Result(caption='清华简入选《国家珍贵古籍名录》', when=datetime.date(2013, 12, 11), path='info/1072/1496.htm')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's wrong with using Selenium? Are you talking about it in general or about OP's case in particular?

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo Thanks; I added some nuance. The answer is "don't use Selenium certainly in this case, but also usually in general it should be avoided for scraping unless there are no alternatives".

Comment: Can you do without it, particularly without web driver, when a task requires scrolling down the page, hovering over some elements or clicking buttons?

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo That's kind of not the right question to ask. Instead, you should ask: "Do I really need to worry about scrolling and clicking, or can I bypass the UI entirely?" Bypassing the UI entirely is strongly preferred.

Comment: @Reinderien I believe a lot of Rookie Coders like me lack the background knowledge to `bypass the UI`. And the docs don't seem to be of much help in this case. Any books you would recommend for us to read up further on this topic?

Comment: "Luckily for you, you suspect incorrectly." My suspicion stemmed from Scrapy invoking robots.txt from the site server. I do believe the site has code to disallow spiders. Maybe this is a side-effect of the "overkill" you mentioned.

Comment: @Reinderien, Your suggested code did not work as expected. Please see the update to my question above.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to dig into this. Apologies for being hasty. I probably would have noticed the incorrect results if I were able to speak mandarin.

Comment: "Someone who actually cared about preventing scraping would add a captcha." I think adding captcha to each and every search query POSTed just to prevent scraping would  only irritate normal users by making it super inconvenient to search. So I am more inclined to interpret the "bug" as a feature in this case.

Comment: @Sati I rewrote this answer. It turns out it actually is trivially easy to use requests after all; I had just forgotten to include some form fields. Regarding your question on reading - basically google site reverse engineering; there are many many guides on this e.g. on [medium](https://devavratvk.medium.com/how-to-reverse-engineer-websites-8dcfe35727d4).

Comment: What are the form variables and how are they generated? How do you decide what values to use for each? (other than the query search key)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128255/scraping-a-dynamic-website-with-scrapy-or-requests-and-selenium

Comment: @Reinderien May i ask why session is on __init__ and not in __enter__ ? what is the difference? Thanks!!!

Comment: @AlexDotis Best practice for Python class member variables is to set them on the instance in the `__init__`, rather than them first appearing in another function. So either the session would need to be constructed as an `Optional[]` equal to `None` and then written in `__enter__`, which is awkward; or just initialized in the constructor. One other difference is that if a caller instantiates `TsinghuaSite` but then does not use context management, the class will still work (whereas it would not if the session were constructed in `__enter__`).