# Organizing things together to form a minimum viable Scraper App

Tags: python, web-scraping, modules

This is a follow-up of my group of scraper questions starting from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/262772/242934).

I have thus far, with the help of @Reinderien, written 4 separate "modules" that expose a `search` function to scrape bibliographic information from separate online databases. Half  of which use `Selenium`; the other `Requests`.

I would like to know the best way to put them together, possibly organizing into a single module that can be imported together, and/or creating a base class so that common code can be shared between them.

I would like the final App to be able to execute the `search` function for each database, when given a list of search keywords, together with a choice of databases to search on as arguments.

---

## Update:

Since there is still no answer to this question, I have drafted a working code that takes in a list of keywords together with the database to be searched in. If this is unspecified, the same set of keywords would be looped through all databases.

I would like to seek improvements to the code below, especially with respect to:

1. Consolidating the search results to a single `.json` or `.bib` file when all databases are involved.
2. Reusing common code so that the whole code-base is less bulky and extensible.
3. More flexible search options, such as choosing 2 or 3 out of 4 databases to search in. (Possibly with the use of `*args` or `**kwargs` in the search function.)

### main.py

```py
import cnki, fudan, wuhan, qinghua

def db_search(keyword, db=None):

    db_dict = {
        "cnki": cnki.search,
        "fudan": fudan.search,
        "wuhan": wuhan.search,
        "qinghua": qinghua.search,
        }

    if db == None:
        for key in db_dict.keys():
            yield db_dict[key](keyword)
    elif db == "cnki":
        yield db_dict["cnki"](keyword)
    elif db == "fudan":
        yield db_dict["fudan"](keyword)
    elif db == "wuhan":
        yield db_dict["wuhan"](keyword)
    elif db == "qinghua":
        yield db_dict["qinghua"](keyword)


def search(keywords, db=None):
    for kw in keywords:
        yield from db_search(kw, db)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    rslt = search(['尹誥','尹至'])
    for item in rslt:
        print(item)
```

---

## The Code:

### cnki.py

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator, Iterable, Optional, List, ContextManager, Dict
from urllib.parse import unquote
from itertools import chain, count
import re
import json
from math import ceil

# pip install proxy.py
import proxy
from proxy.http.exception import HttpRequestRejected
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
    TimeoutException,
    WebDriverException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from urllib3.packages.six import X


@dataclass
class Result:
    title: str        # Mozi's Theory of Human Nature and Politics
    title_link: str   # http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/detail/detail.aspx?recid=&FileName=ZDXB202006009&DbName=CJFDLAST2021&DbCode=CJFD
    html_link: Optional[str]  # http%3a%2f%2fkns.cnki.net%2fKXReader%2fDetail%3fdbcode%3dCJFD%26filename%3dZDXB202006009
    author: str       # Xie Qiyang
    source: str       # Vocational University News
    source_link: str  # http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/Navi/ScdbBridge.aspx?DBCode=CJFD&BaseID=ZDXB&UnitCode=&NaviLink=%e8%81%8c%e5%a4%a7%e5%ad%a6%e6%8a%a5
    date: date   # 2020-12-28
    download: str        #
    database: str     # Periodical

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: WebElement) -> 'Result':
        number, title, author, source, published, database = row.find_elements_by_xpath('td')

        title_links = title.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

        if len(title_links) > 1:
            # 'http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/ReadRedirectPage.aspx?flag=html&domain=http%3a%2f%2fkns.cnki.net%2fKXReader%2fDetail%3fdbcode%3dCJFD%26filename%3dZDXB202006009'
            html_link = unquote(
                title_links[1]
                .get_attribute('href')
                .split('domain=', 1)[1])
        else:
            html_link = None

        dl_links, sno = number.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

        published_date = date.fromisoformat(
            published.text.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        )

        return cls(
            title=title_links[0].text,
            title_link=title_links[0].get_attribute('href'),
            html_link=html_link,
            author=author.text,
            source=source.text,
            source_link=source.get_attribute('href'),
            date=published_date,
            download=dl_links.get_attribute('href'),
            database=database.text,
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'題名      {self.title}'
            f'\n作者     {self.author}'
            f'\n來源     {self.source}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n下載連結　{self.download}'
            f'\n來源數據庫 {self.database}'
        )

    def as_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
        'author': self.author,
        'title': self.title,
        'date': self.date.isoformat(),
        'download': self.download,
        'url': self.html_link,
        'database': self.database,
    }


class MainPage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def submit_search(self, keyword: str) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'txt_1_value1'))
        )
        search.send_keys(keyword)
        search.submit()

    def switch_to_frame(self) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)
        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@name="iframeResult"]'))
        )
        self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
        self.driver.switch_to.frame('iframeResult')

        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]'))
        )

    def max_content(self) -> None:
        """Maximize the number of items on display in the search results."""
        max_content = self.driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#id_grid_display_num > a:nth-child(3)',
        )
        max_content.click()

    # def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
    #     ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
    #     wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
    #     elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
    #     self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    #     return elm



class SearchResults:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver


    def number_of_articles_and_pages(self) -> int:
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//table//tr[3]//table//table//td[1]/table//td[1]'
        )
        n_articles = re.search("共有記錄(.+)條", elem.text).group(1)
        n_pages = ceil(int(n_articles)/50)

        return n_articles, n_pages


    def get_structured_elements(self) -> Iterable[Result]:
        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]//tr[position() > 1]'
        )

        for row in rows:
            yield Result.from_row(row)


    def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
        elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        return elm

    def next_page(self) -> None:
        link = self.get_element_and_stop_page(By.LINK_TEXT, "下頁")

        try:
            link.click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")
        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("Last page reached")



class ContentFilterPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
    HOST_WHITELIST = {
        b'ocsp.digicert.com',
        b'ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com',
        b'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
    }

    def handle_client_request(self, request: HttpParser) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
        host = request.host or request.header(b'Host')
        if host not in self.HOST_WHITELIST:
            raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

        if any(
            suffix in request.path
            for suffix in (
                b'png', b'ico', b'jpg', b'gif', b'css',
            )
        ):
            raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

        return request

    def before_upstream_connection(self, request):
        return super().before_upstream_connection(request)
    def handle_upstream_chunk(self, chunk):
        return super().handle_upstream_chunk(chunk)
    def on_upstream_connection_close(self):
        pass


@contextmanager
def run_driver() -> ContextManager[WebDriver]:
    prox_type = ProxyType.MANUAL['ff_value']
    prox_host = '127.0.0.1'
    prox_port = 8889

    profile = FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', prox_type)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', prox_host)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', prox_host)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', prox_port)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', prox_port)
    profile.update_preferences()

    plugin = f'{Path(__file__).stem}.{ContentFilterPlugin.__name__}'

    with proxy.start((
        '--hostname', prox_host,
        '--port', str(prox_port),
        '--plugins', plugin,
    )), Firefox(profile) as driver:
        yield driver


def loop_through_results(driver):
    result_page = SearchResults(driver)
    n_articles, n_pages = result_page.number_of_articles_and_pages()
    
    print(f"{n_articles} found. A maximum of 500 will be retrieved.")

    for page in count(1):

        print(f"Scraping page {page}/{n_pages}")
        print()

        result = result_page.get_structured_elements()
        yield from result

        if page >= n_pages or page >= 10:
            break

        result_page.next_page()
        result_page = SearchResults(driver)


def save_articles(articles: Iterable, file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def query(keyword, driver) -> None:

    page = MainPage(driver)
    page.submit_search(keyword)
    page.switch_to_frame()
    page.max_content()


def search(keyword):
    with Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get('http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/')
        query(keyword, driver)
        result = loop_through_results(driver)
        save_articles(result, 'cnki_search_result.json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

### qinghua.py

*Search functionality is down at the moment. Planning the try out with `Requests` as soon as it is up and running.*

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, replace
from datetime import datetime, date
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Optional, ContextManager
import re
import os
import time
import json

# pip install proxy.py
import proxy
from proxy.http.exception import HttpRequestRejected
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
    TimeoutException,
    WebDriverException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


@dataclass
class PrimaryResult:
    captions: str
    date: date
    link: str

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: WebElement) -> 'PrimaryResult': 

        caption_elems = row.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        date_elems = row.find_element_by_class_name('time')

        published_date = date.isoformat(datetime.strptime(date_elems.text, '%Y-%m-%d'))

        return cls(
            captions = caption_elems.text,
            date = published_date,
            link = caption_elems.get_attribute('href')
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'\n標題     {self.captions}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n文章連結　{self.link}'
        )


class MainPage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver
 
    def submit_search(self, keyword: str) -> None:
        driver = self.driver
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)

        xpath = "//form/button/input"
        element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
        hover.perform()

        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'showkeycode1015273'))
        )
        search.send_keys(keyword)
        search.submit()


    def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
        elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        return elm

    def next_page(self) -> None:
        try: 
            link = self.get_element_and_stop_page(By.LINK_TEXT, "下一页")
            link.click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")

        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("No button with 「下一页」 found.")
            return 0


    # @contextmanager
    # def wait_for_new_window(self):
    #     driver = self.driver
    #     handles_before = driver.window_handles
    #     yield
    #     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #         lambda driver: len(handles_before) != len(driver.window_handles))

    def switch_tabs(self):
        driver = self.driver
        print("Current Window:")
        print(driver.title)
        print()

        p = driver.current_window_handle
        
        chwd = driver.window_handles
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.switch_to.window(chwd[1])

        print("New Window:")
        print(driver.title)
        print()


class SearchResults:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_primary_search_result(self):
        
        filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "qinghua_primary_search_result.json")

        if os.path.exists(filePath):
            os.remove(filePath)    

        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="search_list"]/li')

        for row in rows:
            rslt = PrimaryResult.from_row(row)
            with open('qinghua_primary_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
                json.dump(asdict(rslt), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            yield rslt


# class ContentFilterPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
#     HOST_WHITELIST = {
#         b'ocsp.digicert.com',
#         b'ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com',
#         b'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
#         b'gwz.fudan.edu.cn',
#         b'bsm.org.cn/index.php'
#         b'ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn',
#     }

#     def handle_client_request(self, request: HttpParser) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
#         host = request.host or request.header(b'Host')
#         if host not in self.HOST_WHITELIST:
#             raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

#         if any(
#             suffix in request.path
#             for suffix in (
#                 b'png', b'ico', b'jpg', b'gif', b'css',
#             )
#         ):
#             raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

#         return request

#     def before_upstream_connection(self, request):
#         return super().before_upstream_connection(request)
#     def handle_upstream_chunk(self, chunk):
#         return super().handle_upstream_chunk(chunk)
#     def on_upstream_connection_close(self):
#         pass


# @contextmanager
# def run_driver() -> ContextManager[WebDriver]:
#     prox_type = ProxyType.MANUAL['ff_value']
#     prox_host = '127.0.0.1'
#     prox_port = 8889

#     profile = FirefoxProfile()
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', prox_type)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', prox_host)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', prox_host)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', prox_port)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', prox_port)
#     profile.update_preferences()

#     plugin = f'{Path(__file__).stem}.{ContentFilterPlugin.__name__}'

#     with proxy.start((
#         '--hostname', prox_host,
#         '--port', str(prox_port),
#         '--plugins', plugin,
#     )), Firefox(profile) as driver:
#         yield driver


def search(keyword) -> None:
    with Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get('http://www.ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn/index.htm')

        page = MainPage(driver)
        # page.select_dropdown_item()
        page.submit_search(keyword)

        time.sleep(5)
        # page.switch_tabs()

        while True:
            primary_result_page = SearchResults(driver)
            primary_results = primary_result_page.get_primary_search_result()
            for result in primary_results:
                print(result)
                print()
            if page.next_page() == 0:
                break
            else:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

### fudan.py

```py
# fudan.py

from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import count
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List, Optional
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import re

BASE_URL = 'http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn'


@dataclass
class Link:
    caption: str
    url: str
    clicks: int
    replies: int
    added: date

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, props: Dict[str, str], path: str) -> 'Link':
        clicks, replies = props['点击/回复'].split('/')
        # Skip number=int(props['编号']) - this only has meaning within one page

        return cls(
            caption=props['资源标题'],
            url=urljoin(BASE_URL, path),
            clicks=int(clicks),
            replies=int(replies),
            added=datetime.strptime(props['添加时间'], '%Y/%m/%d').date(),
        )
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.added} {self.url} {self.caption}'

    def author_title(self) -> Tuple[Optional[str], str]:
        sep = '：'  # full-width colon, U+FF1A

        if sep not in self.caption:
            return None, self.caption

        author, title = self.caption.split(sep, 1)
        author, title = author.strip(), title.strip()

        net_digest = '網摘'
        if author == net_digest:
            return None, title

        return author, title


@dataclass
class Article:
    author: Optional[str]
    title: str
    date: date
    download: Optional[str]
    url: str

    @classmethod
    def from_link(cls, link: Link, download: str) -> 'Article':

        author, title = link.author_title()

        download = download.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").strip()
        if download == '#_edn1':
            download = None
        elif download[0] != '/':
            download = '/' + download

        return cls(
            author=author,
            title=title,
            date=link.added,
            download=download,
            url=link.url,
        )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return(
            f"\n作者   {self.author}"
            f"\n標題   {self.title}"
            f"\n發佈日期 {self.date}"
            f"\n下載連結 {self.download}"
            f"\n訪問網頁 {self.url}"
        )

    def as_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
            'author': self.author,
            'title': self.title,
            'date': self.date.isoformat(),
            'download': self.download,
            'url': self.url,
        }


def compile_search_results(session: Session, links: Iterable[Link], category_filter: str) -> Iterable[Article]:

    for link in links:
        with session.get(link.url) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

        category = doc.select_one('#_top td a[href="#"]').text
        if category != category_filter:
            continue

        content = doc.select_one('span.ny_font_content')
        dl_tag = content.find(
            'a', {
                'href': re.compile("/?(lunwen/|articles/up/).+")
            }
        )

        yield Article.from_link(link, download=dl_tag['href'])


def get_page(session: Session, query: str, page: int) -> Tuple[List[Link], int]:
    with session.get(
        urljoin(BASE_URL, '/Web/Search'),
        params={
            's': query,
            'page': page,
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

    table = doc.select_one('#tab table')
    heads = [h.text for h in table.select('tr.cap td')]
    links = []

    for row in table.find_all('tr', class_=''):
        cells = [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')]
        links.append(Link.from_row(
            props=dict(zip(heads, cells)),
            path=row.find('a')['href'],
        ))

    page_td = doc.select_one('#tab table:nth-child(2) td') # 共 87 条记录， 页 1/3
    n_pages = int(page_td.text.rsplit('/', 1)[1])

    return links, n_pages


def get_all_links(session: Session, query: str) -> Iterable[Link]:
    for page in count(1):
        links, n_pages = get_page(session, query, page)
        print(f'{page}/{n_pages}')
        yield from links

        if page >= n_pages:
            break


def save_articles(articles: Iterable[Article], file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def search(keyword):
    with Session() as session:
        links = get_all_links(session, query=keyword)
        academic_library = '学者文库'
        articles = compile_search_results(session, links, category_filter=academic_library)
        save_articles(articles, 'fudan_search_result')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

### wuhan.py

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from itertools import count
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import post
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import os
import re

@dataclass
class Result:
    author: str
    title: str
    date: date
    url: str
    publication: str = "武漢大學簡帛網"

    @classmethod
    def from_metadata(cls, metadata: Dict) -> 'Result': 
        author, title = metadata['caption'].split('：')
        published_date = date.isoformat(datetime.strptime(metadata['date'], '%y/%m/%d'))
        url = 'http://www.bsm.org.cn/' + metadata['url']

        return cls(
            author = author,
            title = title,
            date = published_date,
            url = url
        )


    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'作者　　　　{self.author}'
            f'\n標題     {self.title}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n文章連結　{self.url}'
            f'\n發表平台  {self.publication}'
        )


def submit_query(keyword: str):
    query = {"searchword": keyword}
    with post('http://www.bsm.org.cn/pages.php?pagename=search', query) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
        content = doc.find('div', class_='record_list_main')
        rows = content.select('ul')


    for row in rows:
        if len(row.findAll('li')) != 2:
            print()
            print(row.text)
            print()
        else:
            captions_tag, date_tag = row.findAll('li')
            caption_anchors = captions_tag.findAll('a')
            category, caption = [item.text for item in caption_anchors]
            url = caption_anchors[1]['href']
            date = re.sub("[()]", "", date_tag.text)

            yield {
                "category": category, 
                "caption": caption, 
                "date": date,
                "url": url}


def remove_json_if_exists(filename):
    json_file = filename + ".json"
    filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), json_file)

    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)


def search(query: str):
    remove_json_if_exists('wuhan_search_result')
    rslt = submit_query(query)

    for metadata in rslt:
        article = Result.from_metadata(metadata)
        print(article)
        print()

        with open('wuhan_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump(asdict(article), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

Comment: Hi Sati. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. Please see [what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: I have posted a revised version of my code as a new answer over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263834/242934)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to focus on `main.py` since the other modules have gotten reviews.

- `db_dict` can be a module-level global constant `DB_DICT`
- the convenient interface is to replace your `db` argument with `*args` taking one or more database names; then this:

```
    elif db == "cnki":
        yield db_dict["cnki"](keyword)
    elif db == "fudan":
        yield db_dict["fudan"](keyword)
    elif db == "wuhan":
        yield db_dict["wuhan"](keyword)
    elif db == "qinghua":
        yield db_dict["qinghua"](keyword)
```

can be

```
for db in args:
    yield from db_dict[db](keyword)
```

- Does this even run? Each of your module `search` methods does the wrong thing, either printing or saving to a file when it should be returning results. As such, any of your `yield db_dict[key](keyword)` statements will actually just be yielding `None`. I'd expect it to actually be `yield from db_dict[key](keyword)` so that `db_search` itself is a flat generator.
- There are no type hints to be seen in `main.py`; it could use them.
- Your model of spinning up and shutting down a Requests session or (much worse) a Selenium browser instance for every single keyword is not practical. It would be a better idea to class-ify any session-level state, and keep that state alive across multiple searches for a given database.

Comment: I've updated my question to fix the bulk of the more trivial issues.