# Organizing things together to form a minimum viable Scraper App (part 2)

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium

This is a follow-up of my question over [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/263474/242934).

## Response to @Reinderien's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263820/242934):

I have corrected the more trivial issues highlighted in @Reinderien's answer below as follows. `qinghua`'s search engine is perpetually down and `fudan`'s server is super slow; so we use the other 2 for the test.

I would like to seek further advise as to how to go about:

> class-ify(ing) any session-level state, and keep that state alive across multiple searches for a given database

Also, whether or not the implementation of an abstract base class can be used to save reusable code in this case and how that can be implemented.

---

## The Code:

### main.py

```py
import cnki, fudan, wuhan, qinghua
import json
from typing import Iterable, Tuple
from pathlib import Path


DB_DICT = {
    "cnki": cnki.search,
    "fudan": fudan.search,
    "wuhan": wuhan.search,
    "qinghua": qinghua.search,
    }


def save_articles(articles: Iterable, file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:

            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def db_search(keyword: str, *args: Tuple[str]):

    if args:
        
        for db in args:
            yield from DB_DICT[db](keyword)

    else:

        for key in DB_DICT.keys():
            yield from DB_DICT[key](keyword)



def search(keywords: Tuple[str], *args: Tuple[str]):
    for kw in keywords:
        yield from db_search(kw, *args)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    rslt = search(['尹誥','尹至'], 'cnki', 'wuhan')
    save_articles(rslt, 'search_result')
```

### cnki.py

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Generator, Iterable, Optional, List, ContextManager, Dict, Tuple
from urllib.parse import unquote
from itertools import chain, count
import re
import json
from math import ceil

# pip install proxy.py
import proxy
from proxy.http.exception import HttpRequestRejected
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
    TimeoutException,
    WebDriverException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from urllib3.packages.six import X


@dataclass
class Result:
    title: str        # Mozi's Theory of Human Nature and Politics
    title_link: str   # http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/detail/detail.aspx?recid=&FileName=ZDXB202006009&DbName=CJFDLAST2021&DbCode=CJFD
    html_link: Optional[str]  # http%3a%2f%2fkns.cnki.net%2fKXReader%2fDetail%3fdbcode%3dCJFD%26filename%3dZDXB202006009
    author: str       # Xie Qiyang
    source: str       # Vocational University News
    source_link: str  # http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/Navi/ScdbBridge.aspx?DBCode=CJFD&BaseID=ZDXB&UnitCode=&NaviLink=%e8%81%8c%e5%a4%a7%e5%ad%a6%e6%8a%a5
    date: date   # 2020-12-28
    download: str        #
    database: str     # Periodical

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: WebElement) -> 'Result':
        number, title, author, source, published, database = row.find_elements_by_xpath('td')

        title_links = title.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

        if len(title_links) > 1:
            # 'http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/ReadRedirectPage.aspx?flag=html&domain=http%3a%2f%2fkns.cnki.net%2fKXReader%2fDetail%3fdbcode%3dCJFD%26filename%3dZDXB202006009'
            html_link = unquote(
                title_links[1]
                .get_attribute('href')
                .split('domain=', 1)[1])
        else:
            html_link = None

        dl_links, sno = number.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        dl_links = dl_links.get_attribute('href')

        if re.search("javascript:alert.+", dl_links):
            dl_links = None

        published_date = date.fromisoformat(
            published.text.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        )

        return cls(
            title=title_links[0].text,
            title_link=title_links[0].get_attribute('href'),
            html_link=html_link,
            author=author.text,
            source=source.text,
            source_link=source.get_attribute('href'),
            date=published_date,
            download=dl_links,
            database=database.text,
        )


    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'題名      {self.title}'
            f'\n作者     {self.author}'
            f'\n來源     {self.source}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n下載連結　{self.download}'
            f'\n來源數據庫 {self.database}'
        )

    def as_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
        'author': self.author,
        'title': self.title,
        'publication': self.source,
        'date': self.date.isoformat(),
        'download': self.download,
        'url': self.html_link,
        'database': self.database,
        }


class MainPage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def submit_search(self, keyword: str) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'txt_1_value1'))
        )
        search.send_keys(keyword)
        search.submit()

    def switch_to_frame(self) -> None:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)
        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@name="iframeResult"]'))
        )
        self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
        self.driver.switch_to.frame('iframeResult')

        wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]'))
        )

    def max_content(self) -> None:
        """Maximize the number of items on display in the search results."""
        max_content = self.driver.find_element(
            By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#id_grid_display_num > a:nth-child(3)',
        )
        max_content.click()

    # def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
    #     ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
    #     wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
    #     elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
    #     self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    #     return elm



class SearchResults:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver


    def number_of_articles_and_pages(self) -> Tuple[
    int,  # articles
    int,  # pages
    int,  # page size
    ]:
        articles_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.TitleLeftCell td')
        n_articles = int(re.search(r"\d+", articles_elem.text)[0])

        page_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('font.numNow')
        per_page = int(page_elem.text)

        n_pages = ceil(n_articles / per_page)

        return n_articles, n_pages


    def get_structured_elements(self) -> Iterable[Result]:
        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//table[@class="GridTableContent"]//tr[position() > 1]'
        )

        for row in rows:
            yield Result.from_row(row)


    def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
        elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        return elm

    def next_page(self) -> None:
        link = self.get_element_and_stop_page(By.LINK_TEXT, "下頁")

        try:
            link.click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")
        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("Last page reached")



class ContentFilterPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
    HOST_WHITELIST = {
        b'ocsp.digicert.com',
        b'ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com',
        b'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
    }

    def handle_client_request(self, request: HttpParser) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
        host = request.host or request.header(b'Host')
        if host not in self.HOST_WHITELIST:
            raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

        if any(
            suffix in request.path
            for suffix in (
                b'png', b'ico', b'jpg', b'gif', b'css',
            )
        ):
            raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

        return request

    def before_upstream_connection(self, request):
        return super().before_upstream_connection(request)
    def handle_upstream_chunk(self, chunk):
        return super().handle_upstream_chunk(chunk)
    def on_upstream_connection_close(self):
        pass


@contextmanager
def run_driver() -> ContextManager[WebDriver]:
    prox_type = ProxyType.MANUAL['ff_value']
    prox_host = '127.0.0.1'
    prox_port = 8889

    profile = FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', prox_type)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', prox_host)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', prox_host)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', prox_port)
    profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', prox_port)
    profile.update_preferences()

    plugin = f'{Path(__file__).stem}.{ContentFilterPlugin.__name__}'

    with proxy.start((
        '--hostname', prox_host,
        '--port', str(prox_port),
        '--plugins', plugin,
    )), Firefox(profile) as driver:
        yield driver


def loop_through_results(driver):
    result_page = SearchResults(driver)
    n_articles, n_pages = result_page.number_of_articles_and_pages()
    
    print(f"{n_articles} found. A maximum of 500 will be retrieved.")

    for page in count(1):

        print(f"Scraping page {page}/{n_pages}")
        print()

        result = result_page.get_structured_elements()
        yield from result

        if page >= n_pages or page >= 10:
            break

        result_page.next_page()
        result_page = SearchResults(driver)


def save_articles(articles: Iterable, file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def query(keyword, driver) -> None:

    page = MainPage(driver)
    page.submit_search(keyword)
    page.switch_to_frame()
    page.max_content()


def search(keyword):

    with run_driver() as driver:
        driver.get('http://big5.oversea.cnki.net/kns55/')
        query(keyword, driver)

        print("正在搜尋中國期刊網……")
        print(f"關鍵字：「{keyword}」")

        result = loop_through_results(driver)
        # save_articles(result, 'cnki_search_result.json')

        yield from result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

### qinghua.py

*Search functionality is down at the moment. Planning the try out with `Requests` as soon as it is up and running.*

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, replace
from datetime import datetime, date
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterable, Optional, ContextManager
import re
import os
import time
import json

# pip install proxy.py
import proxy
from proxy.http.exception import HttpRequestRejected
from proxy.http.parser import HttpParser
from proxy.http.proxy import HttpProxyBasePlugin
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    StaleElementReferenceException,
    TimeoutException,
    WebDriverException,
)
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


@dataclass
class PrimaryResult:
    captions: str
    date: date
    link: str
    publication:str = "清華大學出土文獻研究與保護中心"

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, row: WebElement) -> 'PrimaryResult': 

        caption_elems = row.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        date_elems = row.find_element_by_class_name('time')

        published_date = date.isoformat(datetime.strptime(date_elems.text, '%Y-%m-%d'))

        return cls(
            captions = caption_elems.text,
            date = published_date,
            link = caption_elems.get_attribute('href'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'\n標題     {self.captions}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n文章連結　{self.link}'
        )


class MainPage:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver
 
    def submit_search(self, keyword: str) -> None:
        driver = self.driver
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 100)

        xpath = "//form/button/input"
        element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
        hover.perform()

        search = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'showkeycode1015273'))
        )
        search.send_keys(keyword)
        search.submit()


    def get_element_and_stop_page(self, *locator) -> WebElement:
        ignored_exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)
        elm = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(locator))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        return elm

    def next_page(self) -> None:
        try: 
            link = self.get_element_and_stop_page(By.LINK_TEXT, "下一页")
            link.click()
            print("Navigating to Next Page")

        except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
            print("No button with 「下一页」 found.")
            return 0


    # @contextmanager
    # def wait_for_new_window(self):
    #     driver = self.driver
    #     handles_before = driver.window_handles
    #     yield
    #     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    #         lambda driver: len(handles_before) != len(driver.window_handles))

    def switch_tabs(self):
        driver = self.driver
        print("Current Window:")
        print(driver.title)
        print()

        p = driver.current_window_handle
        
        chwd = driver.window_handles
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.switch_to.window(chwd[1])

        print("New Window:")
        print(driver.title)
        print()


class SearchResults:
    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_primary_search_result(self):
        
        filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "qinghua_primary_search_result.json")

        if os.path.exists(filePath):
            os.remove(filePath)    

        rows = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="search_list"]/li')

        for row in rows:
            rslt = PrimaryResult.from_row(row)
            with open('qinghua_primary_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
                json.dump(asdict(rslt), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
            yield rslt


# class ContentFilterPlugin(HttpProxyBasePlugin):
#     HOST_WHITELIST = {
#         b'ocsp.digicert.com',
#         b'ocsp.sca1b.amazontrust.com',
#         b'big5.oversea.cnki.net',
#         b'gwz.fudan.edu.cn',
#         b'bsm.org.cn/index.php'
#         b'ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn',
#     }

#     def handle_client_request(self, request: HttpParser) -> Optional[HttpParser]:
#         host = request.host or request.header(b'Host')
#         if host not in self.HOST_WHITELIST:
#             raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

#         if any(
#             suffix in request.path
#             for suffix in (
#                 b'png', b'ico', b'jpg', b'gif', b'css',
#             )
#         ):
#             raise HttpRequestRejected(403)

#         return request

#     def before_upstream_connection(self, request):
#         return super().before_upstream_connection(request)
#     def handle_upstream_chunk(self, chunk):
#         return super().handle_upstream_chunk(chunk)
#     def on_upstream_connection_close(self):
#         pass


# @contextmanager
# def run_driver() -> ContextManager[WebDriver]:
#     prox_type = ProxyType.MANUAL['ff_value']
#     prox_host = '127.0.0.1'
#     prox_port = 8889

#     profile = FirefoxProfile()
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', prox_type)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', prox_host)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl', prox_host)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', prox_port)
#     profile.set_preference('network.proxy.ssl_port', prox_port)
#     profile.update_preferences()

#     plugin = f'{Path(__file__).stem}.{ContentFilterPlugin.__name__}'

#     with proxy.start((
#         '--hostname', prox_host,
#         '--port', str(prox_port),
#         '--plugins', plugin,
#     )), Firefox(profile) as driver:
#         yield driver


def search(keyword) -> None:
    print("正在搜尋清華大學出土文獻研究與保護中心網……")
    print(f"關鍵字：「{keyword}」")
    with Firefox() as driver:
        driver.get('http://www.ctwx.tsinghua.edu.cn/index.htm')

        page = MainPage(driver)
        # page.select_dropdown_item()
        page.submit_search(keyword)

        time.sleep(5)
        # page.switch_tabs()

        while True:
            primary_result_page = SearchResults(driver)
            primary_results = primary_result_page.get_primary_search_result()
            
            yield from primary_results
            
            # for result in primary_results:
            #     print(result)
            #     print()
                
            if page.next_page() == 0:
                break
            else:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```

### fudan.py

```py
# fudan.py

from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import count
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List, Optional
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import re

BASE_URL = 'http://www.gwz.fudan.edu.cn'


@dataclass
class Link:
    caption: str
    url: str
    clicks: int
    replies: int
    added: date

    @classmethod
    def from_row(cls, props: Dict[str, str], path: str) -> 'Link':
        clicks, replies = props['点击/回复'].split('/')
        # Skip number=int(props['编号']) - this only has meaning within one page

        return cls(
            caption=props['资源标题'],
            url=urljoin(BASE_URL, path),
            clicks=int(clicks),
            replies=int(replies),
            added=datetime.strptime(props['添加时间'], '%Y/%m/%d').date(),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.added} {self.url} {self.caption}'

    def author_title(self) -> Tuple[Optional[str], str]:
        sep = '：'  # full-width colon, U+FF1A

        if sep not in self.caption:
            return None, self.caption

        author, title = self.caption.split(sep, 1)
        author, title = author.strip(), title.strip()

        net_digest = '網摘'
        if author == net_digest:
            return None, self.caption

        return author, title


@dataclass
class Article:
    author: Optional[str]
    title: str
    date: date
    download: Optional[str]
    url: str
    publication: str = "復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫"

    @classmethod
    def from_link(cls, link: Link, download: str) -> 'Article':

        author, title = link.author_title()

        download = download.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "").strip()
        if download == '#_edn1':
            download = None
        elif download[0] != '/':
            download = '/' + download

        return cls(
            author=author,
            title=title,
            date=link.added,
            download=download,
            url=link.url,
        )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return(
            f"\n作者   {self.author}"
            f"\n標題   {self.title}"
            f"\n發佈日期 {self.date}"
            f"\n下載連結 {self.download}"
            f"\n訪問網頁 {self.url}"
        )

    def as_dict(self) -> Dict[str, str]:
        return {
            'author': self.author,
            'title': self.title,
            'date': self.date.isoformat(),
            'download': self.download,
            'url': self.url,
            'publication': self.publication
        }


def compile_search_results(session: Session, links: Iterable[Link], category_filter: str) -> Iterable[Article]:

    for link in links:
        with session.get(link.url) as resp:
            resp.raise_for_status()
            doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

        category = doc.select_one('#_top td a[href="#"]').text
        if category != category_filter:
            continue

        content = doc.select_one('span.ny_font_content')
        dl_tag = content.find(
            'a', {
                'href': re.compile("/?(lunwen/|articles/up/).+")
            }
        )

        yield Article.from_link(link, download=dl_tag['href'])


def get_page(session: Session, query: str, page: int) -> Tuple[List[Link], int]:
    with session.get(
        urljoin(BASE_URL, '/Web/Search'),
        params={
            's': query,
            'page': page,
        },
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

    table = doc.select_one('#tab table')
    heads = [h.text for h in table.select('tr.cap td')]
    links = []

    for row in table.find_all('tr', class_=''):
        cells = [td.text for td in row.find_all('td')]
        links.append(Link.from_row(
            props=dict(zip(heads, cells)),
            path=row.find('a')['href'],
        ))

    page_td = doc.select_one('#tab table:nth-child(2) td')  # 共 87 条记录， 页 1/3
    n_pages = int(page_td.text.rsplit('/', 1)[1])

    return links, n_pages


def get_all_links(session: Session, query: str) -> Iterable[Link]:
    for page in count(1):
        links, n_pages = get_page(session, query, page)
        print(f'Scraping page {page}/{n_pages}')
        yield from links

        if page >= n_pages:
            break


def save_articles(articles: Iterable[Article], file_prefix: str) -> None:
    file_path = Path(file_prefix).with_suffix('.json')

    with file_path.open('w') as file:
        file.write('[\n')
        first = True

        for article in articles:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                file.write(',\n')
            json.dump(article.as_dict(), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

        file.write('\n]\n')


def search(keyword):
    print("正在搜尋復旦大學出土文獻與古文字研究中心學者文庫……")
    print(f"關鍵字：「{keyword}」")
    with Session() as session:
        links = get_all_links(session, query=keyword)
        academic_library = '学者文库'
        articles = compile_search_results(
            session, links, category_filter=academic_library)
        # save_articles(articles, 'fudan_search_result')

        yield from articles


if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹誥')
```

### wuhan.py

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from itertools import count
from typing import Dict, Iterable, Tuple, List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import post
from datetime import date, datetime

import json
import os
import re

@dataclass
class Result:
    author: str
    title: str
    date: date
    url: str
    publication: str = "武漢大學簡帛網"

    @classmethod
    def from_metadata(cls, metadata: Dict) -> 'Result': 
        author, title = metadata['caption'].split('：')
        published_date = date.isoformat(datetime.strptime(metadata['date'], '%y/%m/%d'))
        url = 'http://www.bsm.org.cn/' + metadata['url']

        return cls(
            author = author,
            title = title,
            date = published_date,
            url = url
        )


    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'作者　　　　{self.author}'
            f'\n標題     {self.title}'
            f'\n發表時間  {self.date}'
            f'\n文章連結　{self.url}'
            f'\n發表平台  {self.publication}'
        )


def submit_query(keyword: str):
    query = {"searchword": keyword}
    with post('http://www.bsm.org.cn/pages.php?pagename=search', query) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
        content = doc.find('div', class_='record_list_main')
        rows = content.select('ul')


    for row in rows:
        if len(row.findAll('li')) != 2:
            print()
            print(row.text)
            print()
        else:
            captions_tag, date_tag = row.findAll('li')
            caption_anchors = captions_tag.findAll('a')
            category, caption = [item.text for item in caption_anchors]
            url = caption_anchors[1]['href']
            date = re.sub("[()]", "", date_tag.text)

            yield {
                "category": category, 
                "caption": caption, 
                "date": date,
                "url": url}


def remove_json_if_exists(filename):
    json_file = filename + ".json"
    filePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), json_file)

    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)


def search(query: str):
    remove_json_if_exists('wuhan_search_result')
    rslt = submit_query(query)

    for metadata in rslt:
        article = Result.from_metadata(metadata)
        print(article)
        print()

        with open('wuhan_search_result.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump(asdict(article), file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    search('尹至')
```